# How does TypeScript not complain about an object that is neither this nor that

Tags: typescript

I would have thought that `ObjectOne | ObjectTwo` meant `ObjectOne` or `ObjectTwo`, not `the combination of ObjectOne and ObjectTwo` which is what it seems from below:

```
type A = { a: number }
type B = { b: number }
type AB = A | B
type ABs = AB[]
// valid as expected
const validList: ABs = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]
// valid, but should be invalid due to {a: 1, b: 2}
const shouldBeInvalidList: ABs = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2 }]
```

What am I missing here, and how can I gain `this object or that object` with typescript?

The use case here is to have an array, that either accepts one specific object, or another specific object, but no extra properties, and no combinations.

Comment: I *know* there's a duplicate for this, it comes up every so often (for good reason), but sadly I can't find it...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah.. I know I have answered this at least 2 times before

Comment: try `type A = { a: number, b?:undefined }
type B = { b: number, a?:undefined }`

Comment: Also similar this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771362/typescript-react-union-type-for-props-does-not-display-error-when-providing-exc/52771517#52771517