# Remove property from a complex type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Consider the following:

```js
type U = {a: string, b: string};

type T = U & ({c: string, d?: never}|{c?: never, d: string});
type E = Exclude<T, {a: string}>;
type O = Omit<T, "a">;

const t1: T = {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d"}; // error - expected
const t2: T = {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}; // ok - expected
const t3: T = {a: "a", b: "b", d: "d"}; // ok - expected

const e1: E = {b: "foo", c: "c", d: "d"}; // error - expected
const e2: E = {b: "foo", c: "c"}; // error: E is never
const e3: E = {b: "foo", d: "d"}; // error: E is never

const o1: O = {b: "foo", c: "c", d: "d"}; // ok - unexpected!
const o2: O = {b: "foo", c: "c"}; // ok
const o3: O = {b: "foo", d: "d"}; // ok
```

Type `T` is defined as a object containing properties `a` and `b` *and* either `c` or `d`, but *not* both.

I am trying to construct a type that is identical to `T` *except* it doesn’t have the `a` property. I tried both `Exclude` and `Omit`, as it is evident from the above, neither gives me what I need.

Is there a way to remove a property from a black box type `T` and keep everything else about it the same without knowing the structure of type `T` in advance?

Also Typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqlC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAGigCMNt9iBfAbgChHRIoAVBWKAMigAokAYyq5CpKABMA-BgIQAbhBy0APsNlR5SnGUmiaRWgEomraAFEuFgB5CANgFdJEADzsyqA+NoA+M+DQAPJcQQC2eMDuZABEKDH+zEIA9gTYUMAAjBiciF5QcTFklAXkRVAiBULl+gWSMQxQAPRNUMo4yThQALRtNpBCwBCSjClpwBkATDlc+YXFGDFlZJUx1Y0tUMkA1j19A0MjY+nAAMwzeegF8QulNYv1G607exD9EIPDSanpENlQVjyJRiADNkslyqtqnoHg16M1Wu1Oq93p8jj8JhBpgDZsCwRCVot1vDNkicBgrHhMFpFMpRhi2uccUDFvj7nU4Qi2jgOuScVSaTpvuMtv8QiyCmzCVV2TFHiTnrteo55KjDgBCeki5LY8XIPHgyFEzmbHZa9LJJl6pAGglSWFPLbbRhAA).

**Edit**: Fixed the original type; added more test usages

**Edit #2**: This question is different from [Typescript: Omit a property from all interfaces in a union, but keep the union structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103834/typescript-omit-a-property-from-all-interfaces-in-a-union-but-keep-the-union-s) because:

- The type in question is not a straight union but rather an intersection containing a union on one side
- It also addresses the issue of removing a property of from an arbitrary “black box” type without changing any other semantics of it.

Comment: Note that `const t: T = {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", d: "d"};` is allowed though.

Comment: Found the answer for why both sides are allowed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776843/typescript-non-discriminating-union-allows-properties-from-both-sides-of-union

Comment: Edited the question to address your comment

Comment: Maybe you can check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57103940/9520479

Comment: Adding Playground link: [See it working here](https://shorturl.at/ntGKN)

Comment: It does work, feel free to write an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Omit` and `Exclude` work fine over simple types (types that do not require unions or other complex compositions)

When the base type contains unions, it is called [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in typescript

A working example, following the playground provided would look something like this:

```js
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = T extends any
  ? Omit<T, K>
  : never;


type U = {a: string, b: string};

type T = U & ({c: string, d?: never}|{c?: never, d: string});
type D = DistributiveOmit<T, "a">;

const d1: D = {b: "foo", c: "c", d: "d"}; // error - expected
const d2: D = {b: "foo", c: "c"}; // ok
const d3: D = {b: "foo", d: "d"}; // ok
```

You can see it working in Playground [here](https://shorturl.at/ntGKN)