# Merge or operator in object Typescript

Tags: typescript

How to get rid of or operator (`|`) and merge all object properties to be all accessible?

Because now, typing `payload.signInMethod` TS complaints that this method does not exist in none "or group" but this one. How to write type to merge all object keys?

[image: remove ors]

Desired object:
[image]

Playground to reproduce my problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2BAHsKBeKBvAUFKAUQDcIkBBMMAGwEsBjAQ2FsQC4d8CpGq6mWiAAoALRgGcIHccABOtBAHMA3FwC+qggGVaihAEkEAJQgAzDnm5RxugwgCyEYCLgATDgHJFcOIuoQPKAAfKA9TRnoIACMfAGtAkI8QRhc4BNCAV0lZBEYAWwDNKA0uQhQwWQhxcRgRCHpYuAzgCy4CMEYQAqRHZzchSskkDhi4f0YEIoJxEVoqBUVyV1dB8QGqshaoUfHJtqhKyNpSIUZZYAQIWUI8xlpqcRGfXamoCrg8uHhXKWs5BaKalwQNw9EQMigiic8CQqHQWAAFB0QNQ4Ix3LBEMg0ABtWIQEBwUyY2FoAC6AEpMAA+TjtTqo9EAOhsekMvRcrmUUAA9DyoAAJOAAdygwDgkKcB1origRLFs3EUCusjgsmBQA

Comment: I posted playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to deal with union types is to use type guards to narrow the union down to one of the members. In this case the `in` type guard works best:

```
type Context = {
  EventApplication: {
    applicationPhase: string;
  };
  SignInRef: {
    signInMethod: 'google' | 'facebook' | 'yahoo' | 'username';
  };
  ExpressCheckout: {
    paymentMethodPresent: boolean;
    shippingAddressPresent: boolean;
    receivePartnerEmails: boolean;
    promoCode: string;
  }
}

const getContext = (payload: Context[keyof Context]) => {
  if('signInMethod' in payload) {
    payload.signInMethod; 
  } else if('applicationPhase' in payload) {
    payload.applicationPhase
  } else{
    payload.promoCode
  }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-CdwjEkktEGtgvavO9oven2+EHUwKAA)

Now if you really want to have access to all members directly on `payload`, some `| undefined` will by necessity have to creep into the property types (since a property might be `undefined` on a specific union member). We can adapt `StrictUnion` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677576/typescript-discriminated-union-allows-invalid-state/52678379#52678379) to get the types to work the way you want:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, undefined>> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Context = {
  EventApplication: {
    applicationPhase: string;
  };
  SignInRef: {
    signInMethod: 'google' | 'facebook' | 'yahoo' | 'username';
  };
  ExpressCheckout: {
    paymentMethodPresent: boolean;
    shippingAddressPresent: boolean;
    receivePartnerEmails: boolean;
    promoCode: string;
  }
}

const getContext = (payload: StrictUnion<Context[keyof Context]>) => {
  payload.applicationPhase // string | undefined 
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwNIRAZwDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7ARwAmmUAhnCFAPxQDWGSAZqVABcUOBABuEAE4BuAFChIUAMrBJCAMbB4yOAAkIAG0iS8AGlIBBAwcIkylanQbNWHMgDIoABUaTgCRgNsACUIdSRJWmwAUQp1AwBXWghsbRR0LDwrG3NuED5SfHMEugheBFFafEJhUQkZeXBoFTVNNLg8W2VVDS1EFH0jKTNC2UbFAGEUaipiKABvWSgoaIk4YAswMAMNRn8UYUXl5cYtnfU9nS8AC0ZMCGFMHrgAczllgF935QQXuABJOChXiHJbHTC-AFwACyEGA1yQtGEAHIXkgkC8DBBkVAAD5QZG8RjqCAAI3RnBx+ORIEYCKQVIJCXukjgjAAttjvl8wbEwJIIJhMBNrmFOEgEsBQccoGBGCBOetYfDEV4Bfd1sJyUgscxvstMNcEFsKi8LLRaOrMGrBTQpVBtbq4PqoAKSQgJD4-KJJNF2YwEAZMFr0U6XfykOykFNko9nm8wR9ZEnZOE4E8oC84VN1g45gAKOUgAxIRhI7qtPo6bA5mbAADaeQKtYcAF18ABKYiEI6y+UlssAOlO212+zgNzu0AA9NOoE81K88VASslypUoMmgA)