# How to type non-co-occurring props in TypeScript/React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let’s say I have a `<Button />` component that can take two sets of props:

```js
type CommonProps = {
  disabled?: boolean
  // ... other “normal” props here
}

type Props =
  | (CommonProps & { action: () => void })
  | (CommonProps & { href: string })
```

So `Button` can be used either like `<Button action={() => {}} />` or `<Button href="..." />` (each time with an optional `disabled` prop).

```
const Button = ({ action, disabled, href }) => {
  return // ...
}
```

Written like this, TypeScript complains about the destructured props in the component function argument, because `action` and `href` never co-occur. Understandable. But written like this:

```js
type Props =
  | (CommonProps & { action: () => void; href: void })
  | (CommonProps & { action: void; href: string })
```

TS would complain about the `<Button /* ... */ />` component not being passed an `action={undefined}` or `href={undefined}` prop.

So how would one go about typing a component with props that must not co-occur? What I’m looking for is something like

```js
type Props = {
  action?: () => void
  href?: string
}
```

but without the possibility of **both** props being null or non-null at the same time, so that we can write for example `<Button href="..." />` but not `<Button action={() => {}} href="..." />`.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: did you try something like `action?: ButtonProps['href'] extends undefined ? () => void : undefined` same logic for href, although dynamically with jsx I dunno if will be picked up correctly. Why not using a single prop and checking the type you do the corresponding actions?

Comment: Maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123407/does-typescript-support-mutually-exclusive-types

Comment: Using the same aproach as here I think is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601795/checking-for-union-type