# How to generate type from list of nested keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have data structure similar to:

```
const Data = {
    key1: {
        key1a: '1a',
        key1b: '1b',
    },
    key2: {
        key2a: '2a',
        key2b: '2b',
    },
    keyN: {
        keyNa: 'Na',
        keyNb: 'Nb',
    },
}
```

And I want to generate a type for the list of all subkeys like this:

```
type DataSubkeysV1 = 'key1a' | 'key1b' | 'key2a' | 'key2b' | 'keyNa' | 'keyNb';
type DataSubkeysV2 = keyof typeof Data['key1'] | keyof typeof Data['key2'] | keyof typeof Data['keyN'];
```

How to write a type definition for any number of top-level keys?

I've tried a generic type:

```
type DataSubkeysV3<K extends keyof typeof Data> = keyof typeof Data[K]
```

But it requires an argument. And I want a type that can be used like `DataSubkeysV1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never
type FirstLevelValues<T> = T[keyof T]
type SecondLevelKeys<T> = UnionKeys<FirstLevelValues<T>>
type MyKeys = SecondLevelKeys<typeof Data>
// type MyKeys = "key1a" | "key1b" | "key2a" | "key2b" | "keyNa" | "keyNb"
```

See [Checking for union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601795/checking-for-union-type) for the rationale of UnionKeys

> we must first get a union of all the keys from all union constituents. To do this we must use the [distributive behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of conditional types. Using this behavior we can build a type that extracts extracts the keys of each union constituent and creates a union of all. To trigger the distributive behavior we can use an always true condition ( `T extends T`, `T extends unknown` or, less ideal `T extends any`).