# TypeScript type that enforces that one and only one property is accepted from another interface

Tags: typescript

I would like a type to enforce the following

given:

```
interface Foo {
    key1: bool;
    key2: string;
    ...: 
    keyn: <whatever>;
}
```

I'd like something like:

```
OnlyOnePropery<Foo>
```

where only following would be accepted for the type:

- `{ key1: bool;}`
  xor `{key2: string;}`
  xor `...`
  xor `{keyn: <whatever>;}`

So basically one and only one key value pair.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question in the comment. I think the original answer works fine for this use case too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAoglsAFhATgMThANgEwDwAqANFAQNIQhQQAewEAdjgM5QDWlA9gGalQC87LrwIA+AQCgo00hSq16TVhxA8+AfigBvKAG0AClDgNZlALoBadQC4Cu8uagBfKADIo+gIYpgcT1jwAJQgAY04UfBgaEKwAVxwIPBU1YlMQURIGCAA3VFFRaygs3JQJCWN6FG5PEOg0Tk5tKRkVAEZCgCMGrAhPBgBuZukVACZC5mAUYwBzQZkoIaEQBkKAEU96Qacy0EhYBGR0BoF9pFQMbHx6zlEJIA

Comment: ok silly me, I thought I checked your previous and that my tsc ignored the 3rd + property...

Comment: You mind if I mark it as duplicate ? Or will you delete the question ?

Comment: go ahead and mark as dup I think