# TypeScript: How to create a type or interface that is an object that has one of n keys or is a string?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I need to create an interface that is either a string or an object with one of three keys.

Basically I have a function that depending on the error returns something:

```
export const determineError = (error: ServerAlerts): AlertError => {
  if (typeof error !== "string") {
    if (error.hasOwnProperty("non_field_errors")) {
      return error.non_field_errors[0];
    } else if (error.hasOwnProperty("detail")) {
      return error.detail;
    } else if (error.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
      return error.email[0];
    } else {
      return UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }
  } else {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Here are the types:

```
export type AlertError =
  | "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
  | "E-mail is not verified."
  | "Password reset e-mail has been sent."
  | "Verification e-mail sent."
  | "A user is already registered with this e-mail address."
  | "Facebook Log In is cancelled."
  | string;

export interface ServerAlerts {
  non_field_errors: [string];
  detail: string;
  email: [string];
}
```

But the way I designed `ServerAlerts` here does not work for me, since ServerAlerts can also be a `string` and if it has one of its keys, it only has one.

How would you design such a type or interface?

**EDIT:** I tried making the keys optional by giving them a question mark, but then my linter complains in the respective key's error return statement in `determineError`.

Comment: Re `non_field_errors`, `detail`, and `email` -- are they mutually-exclusive? Is any (or all) optional?

Comment: They are all optional. There can be one, two of them, or all three of them at the same time. If there is none, it is just a string that is coming through.

Comment: Aside from the `| string` union suggested below, this is a duplicate of [How to create a Partial-like that requires a single property to be set](//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set/48244432).

Comment: Your linter is complaining that... the property might be `undefined`, I guess?  Yes, the question mark makes it possible (in `--strictNullChecks` mode) to pass in `undefined` for the property, so you need to check for that too (or use an assertion).

Comment: Do you really intend for `non_field_errors` and `email` to be 1-element arrays (a.k.a. a 1-tuple or singleton)?   That's what `[string]` means: a single string in an array.  If the arrays can have more than one element, you should use the syntax `string[]` or `Array<string>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, just declare the parameter as being either `ServerAlerts` or `string`:

```
export const determineError = (error: ServerAlerts|string): AlertError => {
// -----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

In a comment you've said that all three of the `ServerAlerts` properties are optional, so you need to mark them as such with `?`:

```
interface ServerAlerts {
  non_field_errors?: [string];
  detail?: string;
  email?: [string];
}
```

However, that means that anything typed `object` will also work, because all the fields are optional. So if you do both of those things, you get:

```
determineError("foo");                       // Works
determineError({ non_field_errors: ["x"] }); // Works
determineError({ detail: "x" });             // Works
determineError({ email: ["x"] });            // Works
determineError({});                          // Works (because all fields are optional)
let nonLiteralServerAlerts: object;
nonLiteralServerAlerts = { foo: ["x"] };
determineError(nonLiteralServerAlerts);      // Works (because all fields are optional)
determineError({ foo: ["x"] });              // Fails (correctly)
```

[Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20AlertError%20%3D%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Unable%20to%20log%20in%20with%20provided%20credentials.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22E-mail%20is%20not%20verified.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Password%20reset%20e-mail%20has%20been%20sent.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Verification%20e-mail%20sent.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22A%20user%20is%20already%20registered%20with%20this%20e-mail%20address.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Facebook%20Log%20In%20is%20cancelled.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20string%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20ServerAlerts%20%7B%0A%20%20non_field_errors%3F%3A%20%5Bstring%5D%3B%0A%20%20detail%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20email%3F%3A%20%5Bstring%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20UNKNOWN_ERROR%3A%20AlertError%20%3D%20%22Unknown%22%3B%0Aconst%20determineError%20%3D%20(error%3A%20ServerAlerts%7Cstring)%3A%20AlertError%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20error%20!%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22non_field_errors%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20error.non_field_errors%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22detail%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20error.detail%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22email%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20error.email%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20UNKNOWN_ERROR%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20error%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AdetermineError(%22foo%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20non_field_errors%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20detail%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20email%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%20(because%20all%20fields%20are%20optional)%0Alet%20nonLiteralServerAlerts%3A%20object%3B%0AnonLiteralServerAlerts%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D%3B%0AdetermineError(nonLiteralServerAlerts)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%20(because%20all%20fields%20are%20optional)%0AdetermineError(%7B%20foo%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20(correctly))

Which suggests you might just use `object` in the parameter signature. If you want to *require* one of the three fields (which I believe would do away with that `UNKNOWN_ERROR` branch), you'd define three interfaces and make `ServerAlerts` a union of them:

```
interface ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors {
  non_field_errors: [string];
}

interface ServerAlertsDetail {
  detail: string;
}

interface ServerAlertsEmail {
  email: [string];
}

type ServerAlerts = ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors | ServerAlertsDetail | ServerAlertsEmail;
```

Then you'd use type assertions when returning the specific field:

```
if (error.hasOwnProperty("non_field_errors")) {
  return (error as ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors).non_field_errors[0];
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you do that, then you get:

```
determineError("foo");                       // Works
determineError({ non_field_errors: ["x"] }); // Works
determineError({ detail: "x" });             // Works
determineError({ email: ["x"] });            // Works
determineError({});                          // Fails (correctly)
let nonLiteralServerAlerts: object;
nonLiteralServerAlerts = { foo: ["x"] };
determineError(nonLiteralServerAlerts);      // Fails (correctly)
determineError({ foo: ["x"] });              // Fails (correctly)
```

[Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20AlertError%20%3D%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Unable%20to%20log%20in%20with%20provided%20credentials.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22E-mail%20is%20not%20verified.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Password%20reset%20e-mail%20has%20been%20sent.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Verification%20e-mail%20sent.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22A%20user%20is%20already%20registered%20with%20this%20e-mail%20address.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20%22Facebook%20Log%20In%20is%20cancelled.%22%0A%20%20%7C%20string%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors%20%7B%0A%20%20non_field_errors%3A%20%5Bstring%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ServerAlertsDetail%20%7B%0A%20%20detail%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ServerAlertsEmail%20%7B%0A%20%20email%3A%20%5Bstring%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20ServerAlerts%20%3D%20ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors%20%7C%20ServerAlertsDetail%20%7C%20ServerAlertsEmail%3B%0A%0Aconst%20UNKNOWN_ERROR%3A%20AlertError%20%3D%20%22Unknown%22%3B%0Aconst%20determineError%20%3D%20(error%3A%20ServerAlerts%7Cstring)%3A%20AlertError%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(typeof%20error%20!%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22non_field_errors%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(error%20as%20ServerAlertsNonFieldErrors).non_field_errors%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22detail%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(error%20as%20ServerAlertsDetail).detail%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(error.hasOwnProperty(%22email%22))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(error%20as%20ServerAlertsEmail).email%5B0%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20UNKNOWN_ERROR%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20error%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AdetermineError(%22foo%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20non_field_errors%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20detail%3A%20%22x%22%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%20email%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Works%0AdetermineError(%7B%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20(correctly)%0Alet%20nonLiteralServerAlerts%3A%20object%3B%0AnonLiteralServerAlerts%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D%3B%0AdetermineError(nonLiteralServerAlerts)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20(correctly)%0AdetermineError(%7B%20foo%3A%20%5B%22x%22%5D%20%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Fails%20(correctly))

Comment: Thank you! That solves half of the problem. It addresses the possibility for a string. But what it's missing is for the interface's keys (non_field_errors, detail, email) to be checked.

Comment: @J.Hesters - As you said in your question, if they're optional (and you've confirmed now they are), use `?` to mark them so. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Any object now matches `ServerAlerts` since all fields are optional.

Comment: That's because you're using a literal object, when using literal objects typescript complains about extra fields. If you use a non-literal object it will not fail (playground link is too long for comment so just add these three lines to your example) `let nonLiteralServerAlerts;
nonLiteralServerAlerts = { foo: ["x"] };
determineError(nonLiteralServerAlerts); `

Comment: @Motti - Thanks! I've folded that into the answer.