# Check that at least one interface member is non-null in typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have a typescript interface:

```
interface MyInputInterface {
  a: A | null
  b: B | null
  aString: string | null
}
```

This is what I have currently:

```
const hasOneNonNull = (input: MyInputInterface) => 
  input.a !== null || input.b !== null || input.aString !== null
```

But this seems very brittle. I have to remember to update the check everytime I add a new interface member. Is there a way to iterate through all the interface members and check that at least one of them is non null?

Something like this would be more ideal (`getAllMembers` is pseudocode):

```
const hasOneNonNull = (input: MyInputInterface) => 
  input.getAllMembers().find((elem: any) => any !== null) !== null
```

Comment: You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) if you are sure there is no additional member in your object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const hasOneNonNull = (input: MyInputInterface) =>
  Object.values(input).reduce((hasNonNull, value) => hasNonNull|| value !== null, false);
```

You can also leverage a union type to specify, that you require at least `a` or `b`:

```js
type MyInputInterface =
  | { a: A; b: B | null; aString: string | null; }
  | { a: A | null; b: B; aString: string | null; }
  | { a: A | null; b: B | null; aString: string; }
```

The type can also be specified using Typescript's mapped types:

The following is taken from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/3941291) answer:

```
interface FullMyInputInterface {
  a: A;
  b: B;
  aString: string;
}

type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U]

type MyInputInterface = AtLeastOne<FullMyInputInterface>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! `Object.values` was indeed what I was looking for!