# Exclude empty object from Partial type

Tags: typescript

When you use `Partial<SomeType>`, technically an empty object satisfies that typecheck. Is there a way to exclude that?

```js
    interface MyType {
        foo: string
        bar: string
    }

    function someFunction(obj: Partial<MyType>) {
        // whatever
    }

    someFunction({}) // ideally, I would like this should throw a type error
```

Answer (score 9):

Greatly inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/1903366) (which also explains how it works in detail), here's what you'll need:

```js
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U];
```

And then use this new type instead of `Partial`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsAyECGBnYB5AdhAPAFQBooBVKAXigG8BtAaSgEtMoBrCEAewDMo8BdAFxQACgwDGLfEVoA+KAF85FYUgBOwBkgA2+OQDIS1Npx7E+AbgCwAKBs2mwCKq5Ix0ALIg84aJRtQAqC4ODiE0VSYAc39AgCM1MOAIzGjreTtrLgBXTDENDmYUDgBbCAAxHLyGAoAKDliAKyE4RFQMbBxPb0gZAEoqGICAeiGoAHcACyRHADcnG3TbayLSitz8zBrKeX6RxgATZC0tECIASXGOLK19qC0GNihgCYYUKBQJq5unidUOMagSCePigTj+qiAA)

Answer (score 1):

If your type is simple, one option is to define all the valid cases. If it's a complex type, this might not be maintainable.

```js
type MyType = { foo: string } | { bar: string } | { foo: string; bar: string; }

function someFunction(obj: MyType) {}

someFunction({ foo: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({ bar: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({ foo: "baz", bar: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({}); // error
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oDMD22BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOZQC+UAPulAEYCGJBx51djzOfEVKUqAblYcuI6hNoAoeZgCuFAMbAy2CkWwBbCADFVGrRQAU2FgCsCcRJACU6BfML6jJzdvMZBBACJ2AC8AukcJAHpIqAA3NgAbMgATNw9jdW8LDHZOKCC2UPComPik1PcDDNMfP1xAkICAGkk8gqLaCKhouMSUtKqvM19OkqgIEhJsEnkgA)

Another solution is shared in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/2690790

```js
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<
  T,
  Exclude<keyof T, Keys>
> &
  {
    [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>
  }[Keys];

interface MyType {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

function someFunction(obj: RequireAtLeastOne<MyType>) {}

someFunction({ foo: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({ bar: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({ foo: "baz", bar: "baz" }); // valid
someFunction({}); // error
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgQWAGQgQwGdgB5AOwgB4AVAGigGkIQCoIAPYCUgExYGsmAewBmUKlAC8UASBFiAfJKgAFZAGM+FAFBQxNHVACibNQBtE3SjLm0GTAvK2KAZAYDeB3QG16UZKTtmAF0AWgB+AC5YBBR0bgpVDWo6enkXFTxUYGQ8UwT1TVtjMwtKRmYUtMddAF8feyCAbi0tf05UYTw1aABZECpwaA9dYUFBKKJUfwBzZt0AI0yJ4CnSWa0aluFEUjVswQCCQQBbCAAxHb3kA4AKQXmAKyi4JDRMHHwiMko+gch5ACUUDcmy0R1OF12+1INzcUFG4ygACJFgAvJFQGoAxpQAD0uKgADdcshuGCTudLtDYVBFqgoii8OjMdi8QTiaZSeSIVTrjC4QiGWikXQ6UKmRisTj8USSWTwZSoXzYVK2axUKhBKgtEA)

Comment: Ya, I've done this for simple types when the number of possibilities for finite. But as you mentioned, this isn't possible pragmatic when working with more complex or generic types.