# Is it possible to Exclude an empty object from a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have a union of two types, one of which is an empty obj.

```
type U = {} | { a: number } // | { b: string } | { c: boolean } ....
```

I would like to exclude the empty object from the union however `Exclude` is no help

```
type A = Exclude<U, {}>
// A = never
```

I tried using `as const` but it's the same result

```
const empty = {} as const
type Empty = typeof empty
type U = Empty | { a: number }
type A = Exclude<U, Empty>
//type A = never
```

The extra Irony is that excluding the other properties is straightforward

```
  type B = Exclude<U, { a: number }>
  // type B = {}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgWwA5QJ4wLwwN4F8YCGEMokUAUGknDAKLJqYxVwgBm8Dqlq1MAqk3op0AHxyEAXDDABXBACM4AJxj4A9OpjjsMBdOjKAlmADmamADprl8nZYwAgkIAewADayAJnAA8-ABo6LgA+Hj4AIVcPbz9AiQJpOUUVNRCgA)

So is it possible to exclude an empty interface from other interfaces in a union?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question..

If you use `AtLeastOne` from @lukasgeiter answer here: [Exclude empty object from Partial type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798098/exclude-empty-object-from-partial-type)

you can do the following:

```
type AtLeastOne<T, U = {[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U];
    
type ExcludeEmpty<T> = T extends AtLeastOne<T> ? T : never; 
    
type U = {} | { a: number } | { b: string }
    
type Foo = ExcludeEmpty<U> // { a: number } | { b: string }
```

[TSplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=58&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgsAyECGBnYB5AdhAPAFQBooBVKAXigG8BtAaSgEtMoBrCEAewDMo8BdAFxQACgwDGLfEVoA%20KAF85FYUgBOwBkgA2%20OQDIS1Npx7E%20AbgBQl0JCgBRAB5itAVwAmEewFswoXeS8UBCOwBCY7iiwCMhoWLh4cgD8QULYAG4QquZQ1rbQpBSU8lAAPlRQSGmu3gBGWQplVLVCaKpMAObyeeDQAGIcHIFOLh5evv7EcgD00xVVUJg19aqN5ZQtUG2d3UA)

Comment: That's a great solution :D

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for conditional typing [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html), you can actually assign types based on some condition.

```
T extends U ? X : Y
```

So for the above question, what you could do is make use of `keyof` keyword that is used to extract keys from objects. When there is no any keys found the type is never so, we can check if the `keyof object` extends never or not i.e.

```
 keyof K extends never
```

So combing conditional typing below;

```
const empty = {} as const
type Empty = typeof empty

type NoEmpty<K> = keyof K extends never ? never : K;

type C = NoEmpty<Empty>;

type U = NoEmpty<Empty> | NoEmpty<{ a: number }>
```

You can finally see that type of the U to be non empty object i.e excluding empty object. Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=49&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgWwA5QJ4wLwwN4F8YCGEMokUAUGknDAKLJqYxVwgBm8Dq5lq1MAORD0UqADwBpAHxMA1nFTsYE+AA8ocMABNiYOADc4AJxgB+GHsMmAXMoDcPFjADCTISLRiPqKQ978AVTdhLi8uGQAfQRDRMWxCWzAAVwQAI2MYXBkAemyYKPjU22gjAEswAHNMmAA6OpryIA)

Comment: What If you don't control decaring type U how would you wrap all the parts of the union

Comment: This doesn't work for all cases. For example `type D = NoEmpty<{} | boolean>` gets type `never` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way:

```
type WithoutEmpty<T> = T extends T ? {} extends T ? never : T : never
```

You need to start the expression with `T` to make it a "naked type parameter" otherwise it won't be distributive over unions. See this [explanation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types).

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7AKIFsygDwAqAfFALxQFQQAewEAdgCYDOFUA-FAN4C%20VtDFm070IANwgAnKAC42c0RMkAoZaEhQAUqmbAAQsmQAbCAEN6ZWAhTpsuEHl5QAPlABGhk%20aJrw0bboAYoaW8EhomDj4Tq5cUABmhnK6knD0AOZQPERAA)