# TypeScript alias does not "remember" unused generic type params or aliased type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-alias, easy-peasy

Please forgive my verbosity in asking this question:

A library I'm using (which is an abstraction of redux), called [easy-peasy](https://easy-peasy.dev/), exposes the following types to be used in conjunction with one another. The `Thunk` type has several unused generic params, which seem to exist only to provide inference for the `thunk` function's genreic params (which match the `Thunk` type's params exactly):

```
export type Thunk<
  Model extends object, // not used
  Payload = undefined,
  Injections = any, // not used
  StoreModel extends object = {}, // not used
  Result = any
> = {
  type: 'thunk';
  payload: Payload;
  result: Result;
};

export function thunk<
  Model extends object = {},
  Payload = undefined,
  Injections = any,
  StoreModel extends object = {},
  Result = any
>(
  thunk: (
    actions: Actions<Model>,
    payload: Payload,
    helpers: Helpers<Model, StoreModel, Injections>,
  ) => Result,
): Thunk<Model, Payload, Injections, StoreModel, Result>;
```

The recommended usage would be something like:

```
type Injections = {
  someFunc: () => "foo";
}

const someThunk: Thunk<LocalModel, string, Injections, StoreModel, Promise<void>> = thunk(
  (actions, payload, { injections, getState, getStoreState }) => {
     // do something
     const state = getState(); // returns local state
     const storeState = getStoreState(); // returns global / store state
     const foo = injections.someFunc(); // foo
  }
);
```

However, if you try to create an alias of the `Thunk` type to have a less verbose definition, all of the generic params that don't get "used" by the `Thunk` type itself (`Model`, `StoreModel`, and `Injections`), seem to get lost, and actions, injections, getState (depends on `Model` type), and `getStoreState` (depends on `StoreModel` type) are no longer typed (they become `any`).

```
type LocalThunk<TPayload, TResult> = Thunk<
  LocalModel,
  TPayload,
  Injections,
  StoreModel,
  TResult
>;

const someThunk: LocalThunk<string, Promise<void>> = thunk(
  (actions, payload, { injections, getState, getStoreState }) => {
     // do something
     const state = getState(); // any
     const storeState = getStoreState(); // any
     const foo = injections.someFunc(); // any
  }
);
```

The best I can figure is that this is because the alias doesn't "remember" the types that don't actually get used in the `Thunk` type.

I have a few workarounds, so I'm not really looking for that here. What I'm interested in is if anyone can provide a more well substantiated reason as to why this is, and if this should be considered a bug, and if perhaps TypeScript github is a better place to raise this issue.

Here's a small repro so you can see this in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-worker-qpi5lr?file=/src/store.tsx

Any info or documentation to support why this doesn't work would be helpful!

Comment: TypeScript's type system is [*structural*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and not *nominal*.  If two types have the same structure, then they are the same type.  A type like `type Foo<T> = {}` has no structural dependence on `T`, and thus `T` cannot be reliably inferred from it (like inferring what variable was passed to the function `x => 0` from the output.

Comment: See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--) and [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) for something like a canonical discussion on this.  If this addresses your question I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this seems like a pretty similar issue. Thanks for the links, I will check them out. So basically it is kind of what I thought, since the type doesn't "use" or has no structural dependence on those types, it can't use them for inference since the alias doesn't capture or "remember" them.

Comment: I read those FAQs and I think they answer the question pretty well and most directly answers the question of why TS can't infer using these types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because TS can infer the generics from the return value like so,

```js
export function thunk<
  Model extends object = {},
  Payload = undefined,
  Injections = any,
  StoreModel extends object = {},
  Result = any
>(
  thunk: (
    actions: Actions<Model>, //Applies generic to here
    payload: Payload,
    helpers: Helpers<Model, StoreModel, Injections>, //and here
  ) => Result,
): Thunk<Model, Payload, Injections, StoreModel, Result>; //Infers the generic from the return value
```

But cannot do so when you encapsulate it, (because as jcalz pointed out, TS is not nominally based).

```js
export function thunk<...>(
  thunk: (
    actions: Actions<Model>, //How do I infer this?
    payload: Payload,
    helpers: Helpers<Model, StoreModel, Injections>, //Kaboom!
  ) => Result,
): ThunkAlias<...>; //Uh oh, there is no Model value!
```

You'll have to create a wrapper function as a workaround. Unfortunately, since `easy-peasy` does not export all the utility types to create thunk this is not possible

Specifically, this line: [`helpers: Helpers<Model, StoreModel, Injections>`](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy/blob/3f632a06e0e8395185980ba8c7b047ed78b2ac13/index.d.ts#L564) is what will cause most of the headache in trying to do this. Because they don't export the [`Helpers`](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy/blob/3f632a06e0e8395185980ba8c7b047ed78b2ac13/index.d.ts#L148) type.

There is a feature released for TS 4.7 which allows you to derive type parameters from typed functions. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607. We can use this pattern to get the parameters of `thunk`. So we can do this once it is released, or if you are OK with running a developmental version of TS as a dependency. Install using `npm/yarn install/add typescript@next`

```js
type ThunkAlias<TPayload = never, TReturn = any> = Thunk<
  StoreModel,
  TPayload,
  Deps,
  never,
  TReturn
>

export function thunkAlias<
  Model extends object = StoreModel,
  Payload = undefined,
  Injections = Deps,
  SModel extends object = {},
  Result = any
>(
  args: Parameters<typeof thunk<Model, Payload, Injections, SModel, Result>>[0],
): ThunkAlias<Payload, Result> {
  return thunk<Model, Payload, Injections, SModel, Result>(args)
}
```

You can view a demo version which emulates this here:
[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3yabw)

The workaround is to simply copy the `Helpers` type, and redefine your wrapper function instead based on that. (and import any other types it needs)

```js
// Yoinked from easy-peasy 
type Helpers<Model extends object, StoreModel extends object, Injections> = {
  dispatch: Dispatch<StoreModel>;
  fail: AnyFunction;
  getState: () => State<Model>;
  getStoreActions: () => Actions<StoreModel>;
  getStoreState: () => State<StoreModel>;
  injections: Injections;
  meta: Meta;
};

export function thunkAlias<
  Model extends object = StoreModel,
  Payload = undefined,
  Injections = Deps,
  SModel extends object = {},
  Result = any
>(
  _thunk: (
    actions: Actions<Model>,
    payload: Payload,
    helpers: Helpers<Model, SModel, Injections>,
  ) => Result,
): ThunkAlias<Payload, Result> {
  return thunk<Model, Payload, Injections, SModel, Result>(args)
}
```

P.S. but at some point, you have to ask yourself whether all this work^, is really worth it, for some less verbosity elsewhere? Depends on who you ask I suppose...

Comment: I didn't think you could import the `Helpers` type either, but apparently you can. This [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-worker-qpi5lr?file=/src/custom-types.ts) shows that it can be imported and a commented out workaround that I'm currently using.

Comment: And yes, I agree, that at some point all the extra work isn't worth it, though I'm satisfied with the current workaround I have, and I now understand that by combining the alias I created with the alias for the `Helpers` type, it completes the inference and allows even params like `actions` to be inferred, even though the `Helpers` alias is only applied to the `helpers` (third param).

Comment: Mainly I was interested in why this doesn't work, and the answers / comments provided here are helpful. Interested in the upcoming 4.7 feature as well.