# Typescript: Type that requires at least one property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider that I have the following type:

```js
type SomeType = {
  propOne: any;
  propTwo: any;
  propThree: any;
}
```

The `propOne` is required, `propTwo` and `propThree` are optional but at least one of them is required. How can I define the type with that constraint?

```js
// The following code is my expectation
let someVar1: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propTwo: "two" } //Okay
let someVar2: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propThree: "three" } //Okay
let someVar3: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propTwo: "two", propThree: "three" } //Okay
let someVar4: SomeType = { propOne: 1 } //Not Okay
```

Comment: Which TS version do you use? Because in newest 3.8 only third case is correct (no TS error)

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski that's OP's expected outcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set/48244432

Comment: I would create a constructor to enforce this "check constraint" and throw an exception if the parameters do not meet the expectations.

Comment: @DaggeJ that relies on this type being a class. However, it's possible to merely construct and consume it separately without involving classes in the process. Also, a constructor will enforce the check *only* at construction time, not later if the instance is modified.

Comment: @VLAZ: Sounds legit :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the same trick even after your edit:

```js
type SomeType = {
  propOne: number;
  propTwo?: string;
  propThree?: string;
} & ({
  propTwo: string;
} | {
  propThree: string;
})

let someVar1: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propTwo: "two" } //Okay
let someVar2: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propThree: "three" } //Okay
let someVar3: SomeType = { propOne: 1, propTwo: "two", propThree: "three" } //Okay
let someVar4: SomeType = { propOne: 1 } //Not Okay

function f(s: SomeType) {
  let p1 = s.propOne; // number
  let p2 = s.propTwo; // string | undefined
  let p3 = s.propThree; // string | undefined
}
```

It forces you to have at least one property at declaration time, and it allows you to use both properties of the type when using objects of that type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAygewLZQCqVgXhgb2DGCAJwQgHkA7KALhgoFckAjKIgbn0JIlQHcEA-LQDOIIgEsKAcw4FipVAAsiUKEJiiJ0jgF8YAMhgAKPHO58EIsZJnA9AH1yd5PZaqtbbOgJTBgAGygQDWQoADUAQyIARlpEFHRoGGwcLlJKGhhogBo0nn5aACIQfkKYPQB6CrIAawiwAKCQlEiiACY40MSsXDyM2hy8pRVM4rcoMsrquobA4OFQ1oBmToSMZN6XfqzclwsikoRC3fNxg-HJmCra+sb5xaiAFlW0dZS+qgHyq4qAOQRgjcGsAAGb0CgAYxA4gQFBgIKMwhe3W8TgIc0I0Q2wgAdFsqGwfnRGCwiJwMRA2ti8eZ+ISqhprNIYI5wQATKAgyRQNnkpoQJbUvbjekVRmeFkwdmc7m8nRAA)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, it solved my problem, but it will lengthen my code if I have the more complex types.

Comment: You can probably use the answer from the duplicate thread, something like this: `type SomeType = { propOne: any } & AtLeastOne<{ propTwo: any, propThree: any }>`. Then you only declare your properties once

Comment: Can this be done with interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

Here is type that is union type of 2 objects:

```
type SomeType = {
    propOne: any;
} | {
  propTwo: any;
}
```

Typescript will require object's type to be compatible to one of type in this union. [Here is solution in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gWAFBSFRgBOcYA8gHYQBcUAhlSANz4C%20UAPtvoaeWQB3OPSasO%20fABsIwKAGdEEAGoMSARnrwkqSFExZiZSjXoaonAPRWKAawYgZcxcrUkATNuV6M2Y4Ii9ABEwCLBllA29o7O8kpI7gDM3rpoBv4CpnRQGgA0AWDColCh4ZHRDk54svFu6gAsqSjphhVWAHJw8jEgQA)

**Note:** This is the simplest solution if you *really* have only two properties.