# Typescript: Define type as union of types with a partially present object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, union

Let's say I have two types defined like this:

```
const type A = { identifier: string, properties: { p1: string, p2: string }};
const type B = { identifier: string, properties: { p3: string, p4: string }};
```

I want to define a type being an union of A and B, and where 'properties' key would be partially filled (but always present, i.e. at least one key should be present). However, I do not want to mix between keys of 'properties' object of these two types.

For example, these instances would be valid:

```
{ identifier: 'id', properties: { p1: 'prop1', p2: 'prop2' }}
{ identifier: 'id', properties: { p2: 'prop2' }}
{ identifier: 'id', properties: { p3: 'prop3', p4: 'prop4' }}
{ identifier: 'id', properties: { p3: 'prop3' }}
```

But these instances would NOT be valid:

```
{ identifier: 'id', properties: {}} // 'properties' is empty
{ identifier: 'id' } // 'properties' is missing
{ identifier: 'id', properties: { p1: 'prop1', p3: 'prop3' }} // 'properties' has keys from A and B
```

I tried a lot of different configurations but nothing seems to work. Also, I didn't find any question answering this issue.

Comment: Is `const` a typo here?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/wee9Ew) what you're looking for?  If not, could you elaborate on what's wrong with it?  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz you should post that code as an answer, it's far more elegant than what [I came up with](https://tsplay.dev/WGnJvm)

Comment: The requirement to have `properties` be a partial object but have at least one key is highly unusual and is the main thing throwing a wrench into this, otherwise it would be much more simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a combination of the following two questions:

---

"[How to create a Partial-like that requires a single property to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set/48244432)" make a type function `AtLeastOneProp<T>` which takes turns an object type `T` into a [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)-like type but it does not allow all properties to be missing:

```
type AtLeastOneProp<T extends object> = T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]-?:
  Pick<T, K> & Partial<T> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never }[keyof T]
  : never;
```

Here I am using [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), and various [utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to iterate over each property `K` of `T` and produce a version of `T` where only that property is required (`Pick<T, K>`) and the rest are optional (`Partial<T>`), and produce a union of those.

If we do this to, for example, the `properties` property of `A`, we get:

```
type AtLeastOnePropFromAProperties = AtLeastOneProp<A["properties"]>;
/* type AtLeastOnePropFromAProperties = {
    p1: string;
    p2?: string | undefined;
} | {
    p2: string;
    p1?: string | undefined;
} */
```

You can see that either `p1` is required and `p2` is not, or `p2` is required and `p1` is not.

---

"[TypeScript a | b allows combination of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both)" make a type function `ExclusifyUnion<T>` which turns a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object types `T` into an *exclusive* union of such types where each union member rejects properties belonging to the other members:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends AllKeys<T> = AllKeys<T>> =
  T extends any ? (T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>) extends
  infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never : never;
```

This is also using distributive conditional types and utility types.  `AllKeys<T>` is a union of all the keys from all the union members of `T`, and `ExclusifyUnion<T>` takes every union member of `T` and adds `Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>`, where `K` is `AllKeys<T>` from the full union.  `Exclude<K, keyof T>` looks at just those keys from the full union which are *not* present in the current union member, and `Partial<Record<..., never>>` makes an object type whose values at those keys must be missing (or `undefined`).

If we use that on the union of `properties` from `A` and `B`, we get:

```
type ExclusifyAorBProperties = ExclusifyUnion<A["properties"] | B["properties"]>
/* type ExclusifyAorBProperties = {
    p1: string;
    p2: string;
    p3?: undefined;
    p4?: undefined;
} | {
    p3: string;
    p4: string;
    p1?: undefined;
    p2?: undefined;
} */
```

You can see that either `p1` and `p2` are required while `p3` and `p4` are prohibited, or `p3` and `p4` are required while `p1` and `p2` are prohibited.

---

For your desired type, we will combine `AtLeastOneProp<T>` and `ExclusifyUnion<T>` with your `A` and `B` types:

```
type MyType = {
  identifier: string,
  properties: ExclusifyUnion<AtLeastOneProp<A["properties"] | B["properties"]>>
}
```

If you inspect `properties` with IntelliSense you will see how this works, at least until the type is truncated:

```
/* (property) properties: {
    p1: string;
    p2?: string | undefined;
    p3?: undefined;
    p4?: undefined;
} | {
    p2: string;
    p1?: string | undefined;
    p3?: undefined;
    p4?: undefined;
} | {
    p3: string;
    p4?: string | undefined;
    p1?: undefined;
    p2?: undefined;
} | {
    ...;
} */
```

Let's test it out on your use cases:

```
const a: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: { p1: 'prop1', p2: 'prop2' } }; // ok
const b: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: { p2: 'prop2' } }; // ok
const c: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: { p3: 'prop3', p4: 'prop4' } }; // ok
const d: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: { p3: 'prop3' } }; // ok

const e: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: {} } // error!
// Type '{}' is not assignable -----> ~~~~~~~~~~
const f: MyType = { identifier: 'id' } // error!
//    ~ <-- Property 'properties' is missing 
const g: MyType = { identifier: 'id', properties: { p1: 'prop1', p3: 'prop3' } } // error!
// ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ p1: string; p3: string; } is not assignable
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCWATCA7YqBmqEATgFxQDOwRqWA5gDRRhED2kRuE5ZKYAjGUrU6jMACZBVGrSgBfOQG4AsAChQkKACEEyNJhz5CpClJFNW7Tt11gAzJOEMmAFgfS5i1avXQYwADIQAIaUAPJYEAAKFgA8ACpQEAAewNjo5FAsAEYAVhAAxsAAfDoJyalY6Zm5BcBQAPy6ANoA0mhYUADWECAseFBxALoAtPUkqlBQkaj5nfGMLSUAZFNBHKhBADbxJeVpGTR4xFChDc2R7V09fSeDZKFNkYMeZBEAbseyTd29-UMTUFeEA+RGUKm84F8AWCYQi0TYADFWABbGDwyyEDKIPyBELAcJRWIwJoAImYbGIVhJgyKYIA9AAqKA+WDQvEE9FIlio9GUzE6JAAyb8Nx0MGTYViMYmRxQAA+UAArpUIAQIugwfIFYKVBKmBIZdJxRL+NKhO4FcrMGqIBrVPIGXSvGpIbBNpsWj1yDtSokUvsoEEsCAzj8bgkgSCwSyAKJJfKbRXkfAgACqWFQLCw8ygbT2lQyMHdnpA3riJWxxa9OwrALK-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-RYW2iKzFjs1LntELLPvA6b1c17Xdf1xb1tN4rAyunNvB+ZlJ12KlHjq1Amva+Quv64bEDOkAA)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you.