# Custom AtLeastOne type not compiling as expected when used with Generic

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have defined a custom type AtLeastOne which ensures that the passed-in object contains at least one valid key. This works well when the generic is instantiated but requires casting when another generic type is passed into it. I am unable to understand why this casting is required.

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECMEMGcFMBNQHsBmLnoBYBdsAdoAuEabSAYwGskA3WAJxQBskB3AOnKQFthJgALAA4ATAPEBmEcACMAgJwAGAKyL5AgFDYAnnligAgtgAysGNgDyAO1gAeACoAaUAFVQAXlABvUAG0A0qAAllaglLDaqKD2ALqEoAAKQVS2AEqwAI4ArkH0CA4AfM7%20BaAAvqWeCZD02EGQTIWgAGSuvuGR6C4xANwaWrr6ACLgALKwZEOQZB7eGqDB8AD88VZZ3OAMfWV9GlxWpKBc9Hnk2EzaAOpI9JREhiZmpNZ2I%20OT05CV3ovxMiIScp9faHY6nc7aABikCCTHuRlM5hetjeE0gUzI3y8O36IOwoAA5rAbPRktAAKIAD0g3DwTH0ngcoFglOwxPg0FAqI%20mIAFABKDylLzzUAgUCsTDaUDwJCwTnYTBBTlWJD41g3ShLUV4mVy6AAOTV11u8QRT0sNianh8QXgfwBQP6C3F5EgoXI9JqoEV%20gY9BuEGlWWgIQJoHdoAARDAozqkAd8Xlsrl5QZoOm4LUggmzY8kVb7FjfqB-oCyhHOeaC3Yi9sekA)

```
// based off of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48244432/14905094
type AtLeastOne<T, U = { [K in keyof T]: Pick<Required<T>, K> }> = Partial<T> & U[keyof U];

type DbMetaData = {
  id?: number;
};

const correctlyWorks: AtLeastOne<DbMetaData> = { id: 123 };
const correctlyFails: AtLeastOne<DbMetaData> = {};

const genericsExample = <T extends DbMetaData>() => {
  // why does this not work?
  const doesNotWork: AtLeastOne<T> = { id: 123 };

  // can clear the error by using an "as"
  const requiresAsAssertion: AtLeastOne<T> = { id: 123 } as AtLeastOne<T>;
};
```

The following error is generated:

```
Type '{ id: 123; }' is not assignable to type 'AtLeastOne<T, { [K in keyof T]: Pick<Required<T>, K>; }>'.
  Type '{ id: 123; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic constraint says that `T` extends `DbMetaData`.  So, for example, `{}` would satisfy that constraint, but `const correctlyWorks: AtLeastOne<{}> = { id: 123 };` would be an error.

In other words, TS is showing an error because there are some values of `T` for which `AtLeastOne<T>` is not compatible with the assigned value.