# Mapped Types with one mandatory key from possible keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

The below code allows to create an oject that contains "k1" or "k2" or ("k1" and "k2") or none of them.

```
type Foo = "k1"|"k2";

type Bar = {[key in Foo]?: string};

const myObj1: Bar = { // ok

}

const myObj3: Bar = { // ok
    "k1": "random string",
    "k2": "random string",
}
```

My goal is to be able to have one and only one **mandatory** key, either "k1" or "k2".

So i want to be able to do the below:

```
const myObj1: Bar = { // Compile error

}

const myObj2: Bar = { // Compile error
    "k1": "random string",
    "k2": "random string",
}

const myObj3: Bar = { // ok
    "k1": "random string",
}

const myObj4: Bar = { // ok
    "k2": "random string",
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbA9dN) meet your needs?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Note that this question seems to be a combination of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48230773/2887218) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46370222/2887218).

Comment: Please clarify if you need to compute `Bar` programmatically from `Foo`, or if you would accept a solution where `Bar` does not depend on `Foo` at all.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for you answer. I had in mind what you post first. But what you mean "compute Bar programmatically from Foo" can you give my an example.

Comment: If you add a key to `Foo`, (e.g., `type Foo = "k1"|"k2"|"k3";`) do you want `Bar` automatically to update itself?  Or are you satisfied with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71277510/2887218) where you'd have to manually update `Bar` to reflect the new key?

Comment: I see, so your solution automatically update the Bar right? My scenario is simple for now because i had 4 possible keys and the solution from @Majed will work, but is a bit overkill every time that you add something to Foo to update the Bar mannually.

Comment: Yes, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Sure, thank you. To be honest the way you provide is awesome, but is a bit complicate for someone that knows the basics of typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work as you desire, you need `Bar` to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where each member in the union has one required property whose key is from `Foo` and whose value is of type `string` and where the rest of the keys from `Foo` are prohibited.  TypeScript doesn't really let you prohibit a key (at least without enabling [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)), but making them [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is very close: For example, `{x?: never}` means that the `x` property must either be missing, or that it must be present and have a value of type `never` (which is impossible) or `undefined` (which is automatically added to optional properties).  Anyway, that means for the particular `Foo` in your question, you want `Bar` to be:

```
type Bar = {
    k1: string;
    k2?: never;
} | {
    k2: string;
    k1?: never;
}
```

But presumably you want to compute `Bar` from `Foo`, so that if `Foo` changes, `Bar` will automatically update to match it.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Bar = { [K in Foo]:
  { [P in K]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, K>]?: never }
}[Foo];
```

This is using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union.  We can call this a "distributive type".  Any approach that looks like `{[K in XXX]: YYY<K>}[XXX]`, where `XXX` is some union type `K1 | K2 | K3`, will create a distribute type of the form `YYY<K1> | YYY<K2> | YYY<K3>`.

In the above type, we are therefore computing the union of `{ [P in K]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, K>]?: never }` for each `K` in `Foo`.  So it will become `({ [P in "k1"]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, "k1">]?: never }) | ({ [P in "k2"]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, "k2">]?: never })`

Let's look at just the first bit of that:

```
{ [P in "k1"]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, "k1">]?: never }
```

The left half is equivalent to `{k1: string}` (since we're mapping over just one key) and the right have is equivalent to `{k2?: never}` because [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) filters out union members.  These two halves are [intersected together](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), so `{k1: string} & {k2?: never}`, which is equivalent to `{k1: string, k2?: never}` (but not represented that way).

So then the above will produce a type

```
/* type Bar = ({
    k1: string;
} & {
    k2?: never;
}) | ({
    k2: string;
} & {
    k1?: never;
}) */
```

which works as you want, but is kind of ugly with all those intersections.

You can get the compiler to collapse an intersection of object types to a single object type by doing a "no-op" mapped type.  If `O` is `{a: 1} & {b: 2}`, then `{[P in keyof O]: O[P]}` will be `{a: 1, b: 2}`.  So we can extend `Bar`'s definition to do that:

```
type Bar = { [K in Foo]:
  { [P in K]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, K>]?: never } extends
  infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
}[Foo];
```

What this does is copy `{ [P in K]: string } & { [P in Exclude<Foo, K>]?: never }` into a new type parameter `O`, and map over it with `{[P in keyof O]: O[P]}` to collapse the intersection.  Oh, and I'm using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to get the copying done.  Anything of the form `XXX extends infer O ? YYY<O> : never` will be equivalent to `YYY<XXX>`.

So finally, with this definition, we get:

```
/* type Bar = {
    k1: string;
    k2?: never;
} | {
    k2: string;
    k1?: never;
} */
```

---

Let's make sure that works how you want:

```
const myObj1: Bar = { // Compile error
}

const myObj2: Bar = { // Compile error
  "k1": "random string",
  "k2": "random string",
}

const myObj3: Bar = { // ok
  "k1": "random string",
}

const myObj4: Bar = { // ok
  "k2": "random string",
}
```

And let's make sure it updates when you add a key to `Foo`:

```
type Foo = "k1" | "k2" | "k3";        

/* type Bar = {
  k1: string;
  k2?: never;
  k3?: never;
} | {
  k2: string;
  k1?: never;
  k3?: never;
} | {
  k3: string;
  k1?: never;
  k2?: never;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiA1gRlVAPm9AJlQG4BYAKEtEigGUBLAWzABsIBnYAIQEMAnZFADeUANoBpKAwB2sBAF0AXJSgjxABWlyJyqF36yA5lAC+UAGTqxW2VACiADwDGrAK4ATCAB54cADRQEgB8CgD8SlAyEABuEIKmlKZifgrkVBQA9ABUUDTQjCzsXHyCKAAUwqpqUFiRBsbp5lZVFDW1hBFRsfFNAJR4UJXVakT1wIYyRk2WIiO1mF3Rcfz9UNmZlNTg0KVCopLa8nDK1Qe2OnoNU2az50dOrp4+foEh4ZHL8bcQjsAQMg8HGqsgAZt8APJQMLWC61CAgOCgqAQvQQmwKW6fHr8JIpRTpSg5PI7KB7FCtdp1fQTRrzIhLHEzfCUmpjGmTab0xbYlYzDZbDLOOAyLhQJggCEAIwAVphIuT1JlMlAAMJwFgMdhQeL8OC4iiJIUisUS6UywgKgT7KDKtUasBa6C6-XVDDYSKofi8QEajnGVD+N1EVCe72+pj+qaBpKC4Wi4DiyWygDMVrKSpVcHQwY9aHDHj91yMMcNcZNibNsoALOmbXbs8HiGGfYXI8XS0bKDJeExOGBeM5oABBDweCQIuZtEm0PxCd04fAYYiDDAp0iC6r5MnWiniKR2VIqadqe52XTjTm3FqaB4udxeXwIN6hRkrH5-AFA+ZgyHQ2FHOgCJIiiaIYli3QrNUySpIS07EtuiqsqM8pRlyJ4dG+vT0imWGrEkgzIR0l50hhWB4ekVK4by2GGoROEkVMlFsjykG0VSnQ0fhdEChkgqmEAA)

Comment: Thank you for your the detailed explaination! I want to ask you the following:
 type Bar = {...}[Foo];
How that called [Foo]? From my understanding we need it because inside the {} we use the Foo. But why this is need it?

Comment: If we didn't use it, then `Bar` would be `{k1: {k1: string, k2?: never}, k2: {k2: string, k1?: never}}` which is not what you want. A type like `T[K]` is an [indexed access type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), the type when you read a property by indexing into an object of type `T` with a key of type `K`. If `T` is `{a: 0, b: 1}` and `K` is `"a"` then `T[K]` is `0`.  If `K` is `"a" | "b"`, then `T[K]` is `0 | 1`. With `{[K in Foo]: F<K>}[Foo]` you will end up with `F<"k1"> | F<"k2"> | ...` (for all the members in `Foo`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type Bar = {k1: string, k2?: never} | {k1?: never, k2: string};
```

Comment: Do we know if OP needs `Bar` to be computed programmatically from `Foo`?

Comment: @jcalz I didn't think of that, this answer is a direct solution to the above case