# Typescript: Not more than one property in type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type `MaxOneProp` where you should only be allowed to specify **exactly one property**. Possible property names are listed in the `Props` type.

```js
type Props = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type MaxOneProp = Partial<{ [K in Props]: string }>

// should be valid

const a: MaxOneProp = {
  a: "abc"
}


// should not be valid

const b: MaxOneProp = {}

const c: MaxOneProp = {
  b: "abc",
  c: "abc"
}
```

My current approach `Partial<{ [K in Props]: string }>` does not in any  way limit the amount of properties of the object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgJwPYQM4wLwwOQENswA%20OARgcdgMbbCiSwCyuAHgPIB2UiKm8uCIAJa4ANgB4A3jADaAaRiD28ZGgC6ALhioQCRQHMYAXwB8tAPRmtACyQBXEQBMYJWADdRgh7UpJ22mLiaTGyc3BC8EsAwAZoARLgklLHAhrTAFtZ2jjDsSCDObh5ewD5%20%20SRBLBxcKhGpJb7%20lJUhNTxYkdEVMPGJsQA0UTDNPQlJKUA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Partial-like that requires a single property to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set)

Comment: this is asking for "exactly" and not "at least", so the other question doesn't quite apply here

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8oYMW) meet your needs?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Your title implies "zero or one" while your question talks about "exactly one".  I wouldn't say `MaxOne` and I wouldn't say "not more than one".  Could you [edit] the question to be clear here?

Comment: @jcalz thanks, it works perfectly. Do you have a link to the documentation which explains what the assignment in `K extends keyof T = keyof T` does exactly?

Comment: It's a [generic default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and in this case it's being used to get `keyof T` assigned to a generic type parameter `K` so we can then break it up into its union constituents via a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).