# How to achieve at least one property required in object recursively for nested objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

For a project I'm working on, I required my objects to be defined with at least one of the property from the object
for example below is types that defines these options

```
type DraggableOptions = {
  identifier?: {
    id?: string;
    type?: string;
  };
  modifiers?: {
    dropEffect?: "copy" | "move";
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  data?: any;
}

export type DroppableOptions = {
  identifier: {
    id?: string;
    type?: string[];
  };
  modifiers?: {
    highlight?: {
      on: "dragmove" | "dragover";
      class: string;
    };
  };
};

export type GlobalOptions = {
  draggableOptions?: DraggableOptions;
  droppableOptions?: DroppableOptions;
};
```

As all the properties are optional(because I also have default options) user can just pass a empty object {} when passing the DraggableOptions which I want to restrict to define at least one property from the object.

I also found a solution for this in the following [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230773/how-to-create-a-partial-like-that-requires-a-single-property-to-be-set/78060609?noredirect=1#comment137618127_78060609) but it does not work for nested objects which is my requirement. So based on the solution I have found I tried to write a recursive one also but could not get it right.

I found these two particular solution to be working in my case.

```
type AtLeastOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>;
}[keyof T];
```

```
type AtLeastOne<T, U = { [K in keyof Required<T>]: Pick<Required<T>, K> }> = Partial<T> &
  U[keyof U];
```

And I tried the following solution for recursive but they are not working. I want to make not only the direct properties to follow this rule but also the nested objects.

```
type RecursiveAtLeastOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? AtLeastOne<T[K]> : T[K];
};
```

and

```
type RecursiveAtLeastOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Record<string, any> ? AtLeastOne<T[K]> : T[K];
};
```

Can any please guide me what I'm doing wrong and what would be the right solution for this problem? Thank you so much in advance.

Btw as I am not able to write the recursive version correctly I'm using the following approach to make nested objects at least on required

```
export type DraggableOptions = AtLeastOne<{
  identifier?: AtLeastOne<{
    id?: string;
    type?: string;
  }>;
  modifiers?: AtLeastOne<{
    dropEffect?: "copy" | "move";
  }>;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  data?: any;
}>;
```

Below is the usage example

```
// This redrop class set's the global draggable and droppable options
// It accepts draggableOptions and droppableOptions but not required 
// for the user to always define these options
const redrop = new Redrop({
  draggableOptions: {
    identifier: {
      id: "id",
    },
  },
});
const draggable = document.querySelector("#item1");

// makeDraggable accepts 2nd parameter as draggableOptions
redrop.makeDraggable(draggable, {
  identifier: {
    id: "id",
  },
});

// draggableOptions are optional and user can just do the following
redrop.makeDraggable(draggable);

// But as I have made all properties as optional(?) user can 
// also do something like this -

const redrop = new Redrop({}) // empty object without any options
// or
const redrop = new Redrop({
draggableOptions: {} // no options defined
droppableOptions: {}
})

// or 
redrop.makeDraggable(draggable, {});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, especially since it seems your example at the end is different (`highlight`? `dropEffect`? `data`? `"copy"` vs `"dragMove"`? `on` and `class` are not optional?)  Could you make sure this is a [mre] where it's very clear what the desired input and output types are?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated it. I am building a drag and system for which I have types for ex- draggableOptions and droppableOptions and these objects contain properties which are optional as I have default for each option so if the user does not provide any option it will fallback to the default options. As every property in the object is optional it is possible to provide just a empty object {} which I want to restrict. I want that if the user specify a options, there should at be least one property provide from the optional properties.

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering a bit I found a solution which might not be the best but as of now working as expected.

To recap, I had a few types in which every property is optional so it was possible for the user to just pass a {} object as all properties are optional user need to not to specify any property. To solve this I found a solution on the stack overflow itself which is following

```
type AtLeastOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>>;
}[keyof T];
```

This allowed to create a constraint to provide at least one property when defining the object instead of just a "{}" empty object. It worked but it does not work on nested properties so if the object had nested object and I want to enforce the same rule, the current AtLeastOne type did not solve this issue.

To fix this issue I created the recursive type of AtLeastOne type which is following

```
type RecursiveAtLeastOne<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? AtLeastOne<T[K]> : T[K];
};
```

Initially I thought this is not working because all my properties were optional

```
type DraggableOptions = {
  identifier?: {
    id?: string;
    type?: string;
  };
  modifiers?: {
    dropEffect?: "copy" | "move";
  };
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  data?: any;
}
```

But when I removed the (?) to make the properties required the RecursiveAtLeastOne started working as I wanted with just one catch. It only applied the rule to the nested objects for example "identifier" and "modifier" which are nested in the main DraggableOptions this meant I can not just define `{identifier: {}}` or `{modifier: {}}` I needed to provide at least one property but it was still possible to just define empty draggable option like this `redrop.makeDraggable(draggable, {});`

Finally to fix this I just wrapped the RecursiveAtLeastOne in another AtLeastOne like below

```
type RecursiveAtLeastOne<T> = AtLeastOne<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? AtLeastOne<T[K]> : T[K];
}>;
```

So to summarise to apply the at least one rule I need to make all the properties required by default so that I can use the `AtLeastOne` and `RecursiveAtLeastOne` type to make them optional but also making sure at least one property is always defined.