# Mapped Types: removing optional modifier

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Given this code:

```
interface Foo{
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
}

type Foo2 = {
  [P in keyof Foo]: number;
}
```

I would expect the type of `Foo2` to be `{ one: number; two: number; }`  However, instead it seems to keep the optional modifier `{ one?: number; two?: number; }`

Is it possible to remove the optional modifier when using mapped types?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Typescript 2.8 you can explicitly eliminate the modifier:

```
type Foo2 = {
  [P in keyof Foo]-?: number;
}
```

Or use the `Required` type that is built into newer versions.

If you are using an older version you can use this workaround:

```
type Helper<T, TNames extends string> = { [P in TNames]: (T & { [name: string]: never })[P] };
type Foo3 = Helper<Foo, keyof Foo>;
```

Comment: Where did you find out about this? I can't find it in the docs. I've seen similar be done with -readonly and I'm trying to read more about it

Comment: @tamj0rd2 From the PR that added them https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype

Answer (score 20):

You can use `Required<T>` as an alternative to `-?`

```
interface Foo {
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
}

type Foo2 = {
  [P in keyof Required<Foo>]: number;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would build my own Utility probably

```
interface Foo {
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
}

type RequiredWithType<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: V;
}

// and then just use it
type Foo2 = RequiredWithType<Foo, Number>;
```

I've built a medium article [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/mastering-typescripts-mapped-types-5fa5700385eb) about mapped types that you mind find interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

since typescript 2.8 You can basically use **Required** utility type

```js
interface Foo{
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
}

type Foo2 = Required<Foo>
```

[utilit types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)

in this case even if 'one' and 'two' are different types then you don't need to worry about that