# TypeScript initiate an empty interface object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im building an app using angular 5 ( TS ),
i got stuck trying to initiate an empty object of my interface.

So the only acceptable solution i have seen is this one:

```
article: Article = {} as Article;
```

Although its seems legit it doesn't work;
trying to use article["something"] will fail because its just an empty object without any  **keys** .


The result im seeking looks something like this:

```
export interface Article {
slug: string;
title: string;
description: string;
body: string;
tagList: string[];
```

after init:

```
article = { 'slug': '', 'title': '', 'description': '', body: '', tagList: '[]' }
```

Comment: Interfaces aren't classes; you need to define a class (e.g. `BlogPost`) which implements the `Article` interface, then create a `new BlogPost()`.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a class. Any object is able to implement the interface.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An interface does not define an initial value for actual objects, but defines the requirements an object must meet for it to be an implementation of that interface.

You should create a factory of some kind that creates objects of type `Article`, this could be as simple as this function:

```
const emptyArticle = (): Article => ({
    slug: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    body: '',
    tagList: [],
});
```

You could additionally create a function that accepts an object that is a `Partial<Article>` - as [described here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). This enables you to pass a subset of initial values to the function. This example uses `emptyArticle` defined above:

```
const createArticle = <T extends Partial<Article>>(initialValues: T): Article & T => {
    return Object.assign(emptyArticle(), initialValues);
};

// Initialize a new article with a certain slug:
createArticle({ slug: 'my-awesome-article' });
```

Answer (score 16):

Or more simply replace `Interface` to `Class` by setting default values like:

```
export class Article {
   slug: string = '';
   title: string = '';
   description: string = '';
   body: string = '';
   tagList: string[] = [];
}
```

When `let article = new Article()` it will already have properties with default values

Comment: Thanks, i though there would be a away to implement it with interface.

Answer (score 7):

Interfaces (and types in general) are just a compile time construct to help the compiler validate our code, as such the type assertion you use (`{} as Article`) will do nothing more than to tell the compiler that empty object literal has that shape. If you want to have an  'empty' object for your interface, you will have to create it yourself:

```
interface Article {
    slug: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    body: string;
    tagList: string[];
}

function emptyArticle(): Article {
    return {
        slug: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        body: '',
        tagList: []
    }

}
```

The good news is that the compiler will warn you if you forget to add a default for any of the mandatory field.

Or if you want to make sure optional field are also specified you can create a mapped type that removes the optional from the fields.

```
type Mandatory<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] };
function emptyArticle(): Mandatory<Article> {
    return {
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Good explanation of the type assertion. It's worth noting that this way of removing the `?` modifier is only possible as of [typescript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) (currently latest).

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp True, there are options for doing it before 2.8 as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier/49655664#49655664 10x for the upvote :)

Comment: Can you use typescript's `Required` util instead of `Mandatory`?

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky yes you can. This is a very old answer, i don't think `Required` existed at the time.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another way to initialize. Worked for me:

```
const article: Article = ({} as any) as Article;
```

Comment: This defeat the purpose of Typescript

Comment: This doesn't actually initialize an empty Article; it just creates an empty object with the Article type, defeating the purpose of Typescript and interfaces. It might look like an Article, but it won't have any of its fields, leading to `undefined` errors if you access any field. The number of upvotes on this is puzzling.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to initialize an object without properties, then have to declare it that it is valid without properties. Also the properties have to be optional:

```
export interface Article {
  slug?: string;
  title?: string;
  description?: string;
  body?: string;
  tagList?: string[];
}
```

when not you have to initialize the object as you mentioned already

```
article = { 'slug': '', 'title': '', 'description': '', body: '', tagList: '[]' }
```