# remove null or undefined from properties of a type

Tags: typescript, types, null, undefined

I need to declare a type such that removes the undefined from its property types.

Suppose we have:

```
type Type1{
  prop?: number;
}

type Type2{
  prop: number | undefined;
}

type Type3{
  prop: number;
}
```

I need to define a generic type called `NoUndefinedField<T>` such that `NoUndefinedField<Type1>` gives the same type as `Type3` and the same type as `NoUndefinedField<Type2>`.

I tried this

```
type NoUndefinedField<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Exclude<T[P], null | undefined> };
```

But it only works for `Type2`.

Comment: For Type1 you need [to remove optional modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier)

Comment: awesome @artem, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Thanks to @artem, the solution is:

```
type NoUndefinedField<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: NoUndefinedField<NonNullable<T[P]>> };
```

Notice the `-?` syntax in `[P in keyof T]-?` which removes optionality

Comment: This is exactly the answer I expected, filtering an existing interface. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering what does the `-?`. Where did you find this specification? I always read the documentation of TS first, but I think that there isn't easy to find stuff.

Comment: Hi Nikolas. Yeah, that was hard to find. Two year ago, @artem told me such an operator exists.

Comment: There is something missing, I get `Type 'NoUndefinedField<Uint8Array>' is missing the following properties from type 'Uint8Array': [Symbol.iterator], [Symbol.toStringTag]` -- this one worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61766383/544779

Answer (score 256):

Use the `NonNullable` built-in type:

```
type NonNullable<T> = Exclude<T, null | undefined>;  // Remove null and undefined from T
```

See [TypeScript: Documentation - Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype)

Comment: So sad that it does not exclude `null` from the type if you don't have `--strictNullChecks` enabled...

Comment: Downvoted because this removes `null` and `undefined` from the type itself, not from its properties, does it? Hence it does not answer the question.

Comment: Indeed! https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4Chm+XALmRAFcBbAI2mQB9iSAbBgbhzwqIGcwpQBzWshIgAJhBigII1nmQIA-EQoB7ZQwhwQrAL5YsYAJ4AHFADllAVVHjJIgGLAIDEQB4AKgD5kAXkzIA2gAKyKDIANYQBsowyG4AugC0isjmVmISIFIOTq7mIKaMDHAU6u5BcR5e2qxYCMog3PhEAKIAHggMJGIuqAA09EyCwum2Xr7YsoQDDL1suBzIAESLs7IIRDwkELO6tfWNC3kFTMWlqGOYc03Tq+xEy7e468ib21i7dQ1gckSp1hlZRzOHoXCZ4KakJiPZALB5XZ6vHZYIA

Comment: @Klesun: good to know! I was pulling my hair not understanding why neither `Required` nor `NonNullable` were having any effect! For the record: check your tsconfig.json to make sure `strict` or `strictNullChecks` are on.

Answer (score 16):

@DShook's answer is incorrect (or rather incomplete) because the OP is asking to remove null and undefined from the types properties, not from the type itself (a distinct difference).

While @Fartab's answer is correct, I'll add to it, as there is now the built-in `Required` type, and the solution can be re-written as:

```
type RequiredProperty<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Required<NonNullable<T[P]>>; };
```

This will map the types properties (not the type itself), and ensure that each one is neither; null or undefined.

An example of the difference between removing null and undefined from the type, versus removing them from a types properties (using the above `RequiredProperty` type):

```
type Props = {
  prop?: number | null;
};

type RequiredType = NonNullable<Props>; // { prop?: number | null }
type RequiredProps = RequiredProperty<Props>; // { prop: Required<number> } = { prop: number }
```

Comment: The re-written solution won't be recursive though, will it?

Answer (score 16):

Nowadays you can use Required to do exactly what you need:

```
Required<Type1>
```

That will result in all the fields becoming non-optional. More details can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)

Comment: It wont, it will make properties `required` but doesn't tell typescript properties can't be `undefined` or `null`

Comment: Worded differently, `Required` is the opposite of `Partial`, and `{ foo?: string }` means the property may or may not exist, and `{ foo: string | null }` means property will always exist, but it's value may be `string | null`

Answer (score 13):

Something in both @Fartab's and @tim.stasse's answers is messing up a property of type `Date` for me:

```
// both:
type NoUndefinedField<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: NoUndefinedField<NonNullable<T[P]>>;
};
type NoUndefinedField<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: NoUndefinedField<Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>>;
};
// throw:
Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type 'NoUndefinedField<Date>' but required in type 'Date'.ts(2345)
// and
type NoUndefinedField<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Required<NonNullable<T[P]>> };
// throws:
Property '[Symbol.toPrimitive]' is missing in type 'Required<Date>' but required in type 'Date'.ts(2345)
```

I'm having success with this solution without recursion:

```
type NoUndefinedField<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I was having problems using the other answers as well when having user defined types for properties.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the answers were not working for me, I ended up with a similar solution based on the top answers:

```
type RequiredNonNullableObject<T extends object> = { [P in keyof Required<T>]: NonNullable<T[P]>; };
```

This results in the following:

```
type ObjectType = {

  startDateExpr?: string | null;
  endDateExpr?: string | null;

  startDate?: Date | null;
  endDate?: Date | null;

}

type Result = RequiredNonNullableObject<ObjectType>;
```

With the `Result` type being equal to:

```
type Result = {
  startDateExpr: string;
  endDateExpr: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwHIHsB2WiANkQIYBGREA8uQFYQDGwAPACpQQAewEeGAZyg56TYAD4oAXigBvKAG0AClGR4oAawggcAM1gIU6DO3EBdAFxRcBYmUoR2ys+IDcUAL6uAsACg-APQAVEF+UEFQAKJcpAC2YFRQiAJqAOZQpFACcQnQIgzMUKCQFmFBAX5+xdC0BcBs4NAyspW+UFnApKjAACKkvNFgqAD8VgLAqGlQAD5QeHY+bZz8fQNcQ6Mdk3jps-Mki2EdXb39EJur0HsLR3wYlxdnM3M3-r4erQEBRY0GAsTAaRyQLfdrtcYnS6DVBjCZpRZfMHtO5Q9YwrbwkFI47dS5WS4I0FglFnfFnQmeKq-OD-IiAmRwJBoTA2QgkChUWpiFhc5gNSBuKB+IA)

Comment: I was looking for a solution to make all properties of a type non-nullable. This works, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The following utility type will:

- Remove optional property modifier (?) from each field
- Remove `null` and `undefined` from each field
- Accept only `object` type

```js
type RequiredProperty<T extends object> = { [P in keyof T]-?: Required<NonNullable<T[P]>>; };
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwAqoPaVVAB4AVKCAD2AgDsMBnKXAIwCsIBjYAPigF4oAbygBtLFGQ0oAawghcAMygkAugFoA-AC5YCFOgxEAcrhpHEAGwsBDZhYikxK7twDcUAL6uAUN9CQoAFEKawBbMHsARn4hbygoMDwwbSgaRFDmCFQfD19-aGCwiIgAJhjBOISknTSMrKgAHyhEOggFSUwcvPACkPD7AGZyysT8GvTM1EbUywsuvx6gikguTGH40bBxuuzvXIWAuA4IZAA3TGiBOCQ0TBx8LOJC-ohItwPoI5PzjDKrvVu2CSjxARGexRK73yumOZ0wQ3+NwM9wITz6xQG7w+QSQ1gsRAAGgAaKAATV4AgAFKRuJSAJT8XhkSjUOiMAlQDRQaI6EoMlm0BhQGn0xnKchUQWMUmc7lQXmy4CoRDQHQKPH0CDY4IrYCkCWsoVKlUU5S+AD05tSuHIqDwqHo2I41k1jAEIm8Os4esCuPxXtWGBJXzhGDe3CJnuW3rBfrB0cDwc430wkIjUd1scQePjuswSdhP0x6ZUQA)

Comment: I like this one. It takes the best parts of all the other answers. It even covers the distinction between an optional property (`?`) and `| undefined` in a type (removes both) which is helpful if you have the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` TS config option turned on.

Comment: it's a beautiful tweak on typescripts built-in `Required`