# Avoiding null value in Storybook controls

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm using **class-variance-authority** to create button variants and then inferring types from it for button props:

```
const variants = cva(
  {
    variants: {
      intent: {
        primary: [
          ...
        ],
        secondary: [
          ...
        ],
        ghost: [
          ...
        ],
      },
      size: {
        ...
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      intent: "primary",
      size: "md",
    },
  }
);

type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> &
  VariantProps<typeof variants>
```

this works fine in app. I'm able to add intent prop to button or fallback to default one.

But in storybook, under controls for intend I get variants from **cva** and null value.

[screenshot storybook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94VfG.png)

If I choose null, my button doesn't have any of the variants styling (I was under impression it will fallback to default one).
To avoid null, I have to add additional type under button props, and by that basically overwrite the one inferred from **cva**.

So how can I get fallback when clicking null, or how not to see null value at all without overwriting inferred type from **cva**

when I add to my button props

```
type ButtonProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> &
  VariantProps<typeof variants> & {
     intent?: string;
  };
```

null value is gone

Answer (score 0):

I left an inquiry on cva github and received the reply below.
https://github.com/joe-bell/cva/issues/253

I think there will be a patch soon, friends.

Or, here is also alternative.
[remove null or undefined from properties of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050011/remove-null-or-undefined-from-properties-of-a-type)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).