# class-variance-authority variants allows "null" value but shouldn't

Tags: typescript, storybook

I use cva like this:

```
export const checkboxVariants = cva('border ...', {
    variants: {
      size: {
        sm: 'h-4 w-4',
        md: 'h-5 w-5',
        lg: 'h-6 w-6',
      },
  },    
  defaultVariants: {
    size: 'md',
  },
});
```

and

```
type CheckboxProps = VariantProps<typeof checkboxVariants>
```

but when checking component props I can see that null value is also allowed and if null is passed none of size classes is applied.
[image]

How to remove null from available values?

One problem is in usage and another in storybook because it show that null is allowed and it doesn't look good with that:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left an inquiry on cva github and received the reply below.
https://github.com/joe-bell/cva/issues/253

I think there will be a patch soon, friends.

Or, here is also alternative.
[remove null or undefined from properties of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050011/remove-null-or-undefined-from-properties-of-a-type)