# Infer Type of interface from Map type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am trying to make `Required` Mapping type for older versions of Typescript (Like 2.6.2 that is what Ionic Framework 3 uses).

I have this until now:

```
declare type MakeRequired<T, K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: string
}

declare type MyRequiredType = MakeRequired<MyInterface, keyof MyInterface>
```

It makes optional properties of `T`(`MyInterface`) required but of course it transforms all of them types to `strings`.

So

```
interface MyInterface {
    optional?: Function
}
```

ends like

```
MyRequiredType {
   optional:string
}
```

Is there a way to says "take the type of T[P]"?

I tried:

```
[P in K]: T[K]
[P in K]: typeof T[K]
[P in K]: T[P]
```

I am not fluent on Mapping types and I have no idea where to go now.

Comment: Your `T` is not used. Some typo?

Comment: Do you want to make all of the properties of type `T` required?

Comment: @unional Yes I want to make all `T` properties required. That is why I injected `T` because I Thought I would need it (but I do not know how to use it)

Comment: I think this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier/49655664#49655664

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir kind of, although it makes the properties types as ' type | undefined' I am looking if I can change that.

Comment: @distante Not sure you can remove the undefine from a type prior to `2.8` (this is where we get things like `Exclude` and `Extract`). Note, it only appers with `strictNullChecks` turned on.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I see, I would need to refactor my code to be sure I handle the _Object is possibly 'undefined'_ errors.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: `type-plus` author here.

If you want to get a type that has all properties in type `T` required, you can use the build in `Required<T>` type.

Here is the type definition for `Required<T>`:

```
type Required<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```

If you want to get a specific part of the type required, you can use `RequiredPick<T, U>` or `RequiredExcept<T, U>` in [type-plus](https://github.com/unional/type-plus)

The code is rather simple so I also post it here:

```
type RequiredPick<T, U extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, U>> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>>

type RequiredExcept<T, U extends keyof T> = Required<Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, U>>> & Pick<T, U>
```

You can also use the `RecursiveRequired<T>` if that's what you want.

UPDATE: this requires mapped type improvement added in TypeScript 2.8

Comment: Conditional type don't work with 2.6 which is what version OP mentions targeting in the question ..

Comment: I see. It requires mapped type improvement (not conditional type), but you are correct, this requires TS 2.8.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. The `-?` syntax is what is required (coffee hasn't kicked in yet :) )

Comment: That's all good. I didn't know it needs TS 2.8 to begin with. :)