# In Typescript, how to use a string type union to constraint a key from another type or interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

If I have:

```js
type Op = 'AND' | 'OR';
```

I know that I can write:

```js
type Exp<T> = {
   [_ in Op]: T[];
};
```

Such that all of the following lines are valid

```js
let a: Exp<number> = { OR: [4] };
let b: Exp<number> = { AND: [5] };
let c: Exp<number> = { AND: [1], OR: [2, 3] };
```

My question is that can I write it in such a way that, `a` and `b` are valid, but `c` is not? Namely, only one key is allowed, and the key is of type `Op`.

Even if I iterate all the `Op` types like this:

```
type Exp<T> = { AND: T[] } | { OR: T[] };
```

It still won't do what I want it to do. I am guessing it is due to declaration merging?

Pretty new to typescript. Looking for an elegant way to express this.

Comment: Yes this is possible i'll post a solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several different way's to achieve what you're wanting, which way is the best depends on you're actual use case which i can't derive from the example.

These are some ways to achieve what you want.

Way 1: Passing the Key.

```
type Exp<T, K extends Op> = Record<K, T[]>

let a: Exp<number, "OR"> = { OR: [4] }; //pass
let b: Exp<number, "AND"> = { AND: [5] }; //pass
let c: Exp<number, "And"> = { AND: [1], OR: [2, 3] }; //fail
let c: Exp<number, Op> = { AND: [1], OR: [2, 3] }; // pass
```

Way 2: Making Each key of OP a XOR in this case you no longer have to pass the key.

```
export type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };

type Op = 'AND' | 'OR';

type Exp<T> = XOR<Pick<Record<Op, T[]>, "AND">, Pick<Record<Op, T[]>, "OR">>

let a: Exp<number> = { OR: [4] }; //pass
let b: Exp<number> = { AND: [5] }; //pass
let c: Exp<number> = { AND: [1], OR: [2, 3] }; //fail
```

Way 3: Note this is the automatically generated version and it's not pretty, i do this simply to show it as being possible. This solution CANNOT be made to infinite depth without overloads this is because Unions cannot be iterated over however this shows it to Depth Nine. I post this only because of the interest this got.

```
// add an element to the end of a tuple
type Push<L extends any[], T> =
  ((r: any, ...x: L) => void) extends ((...x: infer L2) => void) ?
  { [K in keyof L2]-?: K extends keyof L ? L[K] : T } : never

// convert a union to an intersection: X | Y | Z ==> X & Y & Z
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// convert a union to an overloaded function X | Y ==> ((x: X)=>void) & ((y:Y)=>void)     
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never>;

// convert a union to a tuple X | Y => [X, Y]
// a union of too many elements will become an array instead
type UnionToTuple<U> = UTT0<U> extends infer T ? T extends any[] ?
  Exclude<U, T[number]> extends never ? T : U[] : never : never

// each type function below pulls the last element off the union and 
// pushes it onto the list it builds
type UTT0<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT1<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT1<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT2<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT2<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT3<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT3<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT4<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT4<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT5<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT5<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT6<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT6<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT7<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT7<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT8<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT8<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTT9<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTT9<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? Push<UTTX<Exclude<U, A>>, A> : []
type UTTX<U> = []; // bail out

export type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
export type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };

type DeepXOR<Obj, T extends any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof Obj
        ? XOR<Pick<Obj, T[K]>, ((..._: T) => any) extends ((_: any, ..._1: infer TAIL) => any)
            ? DeepXOR<Obj, TAIL>[0] extends never
                ? never
                : DeepXOR<Obj, TAIL>[0]
            : never
            >
        : never;
};


interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    dob: Date;
}


type PersonXOR = DeepXOR<Person, UnionToTuple<keyof Person>>[0]

const test: PersonXOR = {name: "shanon"}; // pass
const test1: PersonXOR = {age: 24}; // pass
const test2: PersonXOR = {dob: new Date()}; // pass
const test3: PersonXOR = {name: "shanon", dob: new Date()} // fail
```

EDIT Way 4:

[@dragomirtitian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) reminded me you can actually create a strict union by joining a each object/key pair (singular pair) and intersecting it with a partial of the other pairs with their type values set to never. Probably the best cleanest way

```
type Op = 'AND' | 'OR' | "NOT";


type Exp<T> = Op extends infer D ?
    D extends any ? {
   [_ in D]: T[];
}: never : never;

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

let a: StrictUnion<Exp<number>> = { OR: [4] }; // no error
let b: StrictUnion<Exp<number>> = { AND: [5] }; // no error
let c: StrictUnion<Exp<number>> = { AND: [1], OR: [2, 3] }; // error
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks.

Comment: Note it is possible to automatically generate an XOR for every key aswell

Comment: I am playing around with that idea too, and having more than two operations. Would love to see how you would do it. You seem to be awfully good at this.

Comment: EDIT: sorry posted an edit to the edit messed up last line

Comment: This will take me a bit longer to digest, but this is very cool. Thanks again.

Comment: @ShanonJackson really appreciating the comments in Way 3.

Comment: No problem, hope they help.

Comment: Sorry I had to ask but what on earth is the "-" in this expr `[K in keyof L2]-?:` doing there?

Comment: minus optional so basically make it required

Comment: Ha Is this documented any where? So `-?` can be removed here? EDIT: nvm found out reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier

Comment: it's also semi documented in the type defintions for Requried and Partial in the typerscript  standard library.

Added a way4 which is the cleanest and best solution. curtosity of @dragomirtitian