# Defining the inverse of Partial<T> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript has a `Partial` type defined by default, so that you can say `Partial<{x: number, y: string}>` to get a type like `{x?: number, y?: string}` (the type's properties become optional). It is defined as

```js
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P]
}
```

I am trying to define the inverse, let's call it `Full<T>`, which makes sure all properties in the object are required. I started with the obvious definition:

```js
type Full<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
```

Which is just `Partial` with the question mark removed. Unfortunately, this doesn't work—optional properties remain optional. It seems typescript somehow, in some circumstances, preserves information about the requiredness of the property names in the `keyof` type.

Interestingly, if you store that type in an intermediate type name, that information is dropped. I.e. this works:

```js
type Config = {foo: number, bar?: string}
type ConfigKey = keyof Config
type FullConfig = {[K in ConfigKey]: Config[K]}
```

In `FullConfig` (at least with TypeScript 3.3), `bar` is required. But if you inline `keyof Config` into the definition of `FullConfig`, it is optional again.

I'd like this to be a single, easy-to-use type, and since I'm not aware of a way for a type declaration to define local types, this hack doesn't seem to help much there.

Is there any trick I'm missing?

Comment: I belive this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier/49655664#49655664

Comment: It is! Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Mapped types are not all created equal. Homomorphic mapped types preserve modifiers of the mapped type. From the [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563) introducing this feature:

> With this PR we preserve property modifiers in homomorphic (structure preserving) mapped types. A mapped type of the form `{ [P in keyof T]: X }` is homomorphic with `T` (because it has the same set of properties as `T`) and now preserves the optional and readonly modifiers as they exist on the properties in `T`.

Starting from 2.8 you can remove modifiers from such types using a `-` (see [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919)) :

```
type Full<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
}
```

**Note**

You can use the predefined `Required` type from the standard library which does the exact same thing as `Full`.

Comment: Note that `Full<T>` is better known as [`Required<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1418-L1423) from the standard library.

Answer (score 13):

Since TypeScript 2.8, we now have the `Required<Type>` utility Type.

From the docs:

> Constructs a type consisting of all properties of Type set to required. The opposite of Partial.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype

Answer (score 3):

`type UndoPartial<T> = T extends Partial<infer R> ? R : T;`

Answer (score 0):

The pointwise reversal of Partial:

```
type Require<T, U extends keyof T> = T & {[key in U]-?: T[U]}
```

---

```
type MyType = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: boolean;
}
type MyTypePartial = Partial<MyType>
type MyType2 = Require<MyTypePartial, 'prop1'|'prop2'>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).