# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a button component. I simply pass it just one `onClick` prop out of many optional props I've defined:

```js
const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement> = e => {
        props.onClick(e);
    }
    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={handleClick}>
            {props.children}
        </StyledButton>
    );
};
```

Then I'm using it like this:

```js
<Button onClick={(e) => {
    console.log(e);
}}>Click me!</Button>
```

Now how can as per the error mentioned in question, object be possibly undefined? I'm clearly passing the function to it and that too as per the type definition. So, I'm passing an object to it. Simple enough!

```js
...
onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>
...
```

I've added a few more strict checks in this project recently and relevant one's are:

```js
"strictFunctionTypes": true,
"strictNullChecks": true
```

`strict:true` being already present, this error never occurred.

What's the issue here?

**Update - Types added**

```js
export interface IBaseButtonProps {
    type?: ButtonType;
    disabled?: boolean;
    size?: ButtonSize;
    block?: boolean;
    loading?: boolean | { delay?: number };
    icon?: string;
    className?: string;
    prefixCls?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export type AnchorButtonProps = {
    href: string,
    target?: string,
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>
} & IBaseButtonProps & Omit<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type' | 'onClick'>;


export type NativeButtonProps = {
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>,
    htmlType?: ButtonHTMLType
} & IBaseButtonProps & Omit<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type' | 'onClick'>;

export type ButtonProps = Partial<AnchorButtonProps & NativeButtonProps>
```

Notes:

The possible solution is to either destructure the props and add the default prop. Or use `defaultProps` from React. But not sure if I should require that really with Typescript.

Comment: `onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>` means `onClick` can be undefined.

Comment: Because it's optional?

Comment: Remove the `?` to make the `onClick` required. If it is optional it can by defintion be undefined

Comment: Since I can't remove the `?` from `onClick`, would adding defaultProps be a good idea along with typescript? Seems like I've to do it now. But I've read in many articles to handle `defaultProps` with TS only

Comment: It's still the same guys even after removing optional mark

Comment: I have the same problem and solved it. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70452169/621951

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Now how can as per the erro mentioned in question, object be possibly undefined? [sic]

The use of `Partial<T>` around `export type ButtonProps = Partial<AnchorButtonProps & NativeButtonProps>` causes `onClick` to be optional. When we use `Partial<T>`, all the properties receive the `?` and thus become optional, which means that all of them can be undefined.

There are two approached to a fix: one is to keep `ButtonProps` the same with `onClick` as optional, and to check that `onClick` is defined before calling it (fix 1); the other is to change `ButtonProps` to make `onClick` required (fix 2 and 3).

#### Fix 1: `onClick` remains optional

Use the `ButtonProps` that you already have, and then check that `onClick` is defined before calling it. This is [what antd does](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/button/button.tsx#L211-L213) in the code you linked in the comments.

```
const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<
    HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement
  > = e => {
    if (props.onClick) props.onClick(e); // works
  };
};
```

#### Fix 2: `onClick` becomes required

Change `ButtonProps` by not applying the `Partial` to the `NativeButtonProps`:

```
type ButtonProps1 = Partial<AnchorButtonProps> & NativeButtonProps;

const Button1 = (props: ButtonProps1) => {
  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<
    HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement
  > = e => {
    props.onClick(e); // works
  };
};
```

#### Fix 3: `onClick` becomes required too

Define a `RequireKeys` type, which lets you to specify the keys that are not optional.

```js
type RequireKeys<T, TNames extends keyof T> = T &
  { [P in keyof T]-?: P extends TNames ? T[P] : never };

type ButtonProps2 = RequireKeys<ButtonProps, "onClick">;

const Button2 = (props: ButtonProps2) => {
  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<
    HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement
  > = e => {
    props.onClick(e); // works
  };
};
```

The answers to [Mapped Types: removing optional modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655419/mapped-types-removing-optional-modifier) have more information about how I defined `RequireKeys<T>`.

Comment: Very new to Typescript. So taking step by step understanding from this production level code here - https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/button/button.tsx#L98
They use the same way. Would it be version issue?

Comment: If you see they don't specify any `defaultProps` for `onClick` in their class component of  Button

Comment: Plus all this is fine. But somehow I feel it's getting complicated just for having types for props. Importantly using any of the above approaches gets me an error on Button props itself now for assignability.
`Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ href: never; target: never; onClick: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void; type: never; disabled: never; size: never; block: never; loading: never; icon: never; className: never; ... 266 more ...; value: never; }': href, target, onClick, type, and 272 more.ts(2322)`

Comment: This doesn't works if I introduce type of `React.FC` to `Button` component above

Comment: The antd code that you linked is making sure that `onClick` is defined before invoking `onClick`: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/button/button.tsx#L211-L213 I have updated my answer to show that as a possible solution.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin option 1 could be replaced with [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)? or or should `if` always be used? I have a similar problem but if I try to use for example `this?.bar?.foo?.baz` the error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)` continue.

Answer (score 102):

With Typescript 3.7+, you can also use optional chaining to invoke the optional prop method:

```
const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<
    HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement
  > = e => {
    props.onClick?.(e); // works
  };
};
```

You can read more about using optional chaining - https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/optional-chaining-helps-to-avoid-undefined-is-not-a-function-exceptions/

Comment: this is slick and much better than the excepted answer!

Comment: accepted answer* (shakes head at passive agreesive comment)

Comment: @SimpleFellow I cannot change my answer two years later and esp. when language supported something entirely new to make it better. This phase in 2019 was a struggle and hence the questions on SO. Absorb the history, mate!

Answer (score 10):

**Just a clear cut answer**

`if (props.onClick) props.onClick(e);`

if you are defining a function props and want it to be optional, define it as,

```
export type ButtonProps = {
  function?: () => void;
};
```

**Explanation:**
If you want to use a function as props, there may be instances when you want to pass that function (as props) and there may be other instances where you don't want to pass it.

for example,

> Common Code  WHERE calling the `<Home/>` component, say **index.ts/index.js**

```
function myfunction(){
  //do something
  alert("hello")
}

return (
  <>
     <Home myfunction={myfunction}/>    //passing prop
     <Home/>                            // not passing
  </>
)
```

> In JS, **home.js**

```
export default function Home({myfunction}) {
  const const1 = "Hello World"
  return (
    //do something
    myfunction();      //IMPORTANT line
  )
}
```

> Now, its almost equivalent in TS, **home.ts**

In TS, we define types of everything. So, in that case we have to define type of this function `myfunction` also, that we are passing.

So, for this function, we realise that,

- It recieves no params, so `()` (empty parenthesis) is enough, if any params are there, we need to define types for them also.
- Returns nothing, so return type `void`

```
export type HomeProps = {
  myfunction?: () => void;
};

export default function Home({ myfunction }: HomeProps) {
  const const1 = "Hello World"
  return (
    //do something
    if (myfunction) myfunction();      //IMPORTANT line
  )
}
```

---

Hint: above answer

Answer (score 8):

The logical operator AND (&&) returns either the value of the first falsy operand it finds or the value of the last operand if all values are truthy ([Source](https://www.becomebetterprogrammer.com/javascript-logical-operators-returns-non-booleans/#How_AND_Operator_Works)). Therefore, we can simply write:

```
 (props.onClick && props.onClick(e));
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: It checks if its undefined or not. If not proceed the onLick(e)

Comment: smooth solution!

Answer (score 7):

I was creating my own custom MUI button and this is how I did it.

```js
interface ButtonTypes {
  handleClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined
}
```

On the button component

```
<LoadingButton
  onClick={(e) =>handleClick && handleClick(e)}
>
  {"Send"}
</LoadingButton>
```

If you're using VScode, hover on the `OnClick` property and you should see the expected types.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution is too much confusing I was getting the error
`Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined`

It can be easily solved by removing `?` from `MyProps` 
**For Example**

```
type CounterProps = {
    value : number,
    selected? : boolean,
    onDelete? :(id : number) => void,
    //remove ? from onDelete to solve the problem
    id? : any,
}

// bottom line will shows Cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
```

[A good explanation is provided here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-invoke-an-object-which-is-possibly-undefined#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22Cannot%20invoke%20an,(%3F.)%2C%20e.g.%20employee.)

Answer (score 1):

### The best variant is to use `?.call(this: unknown, ...args: any[])` or `?.apply(this: unknown, args: any[])` methods

So, lets imagine we have next declarations

```js
type callback = ((x: number, y: number) => number) | null;

let a: callback;
let b: callback;

a = (x, y) => x + y;   // it works with arrow functions
b = function (x, y) {  // and normal functions
  return x + y;
};

function x(cb1: callback, cb2: callback) {
  console.log(cb1?.call(0, 5, 6));     // in this case you
  console.log(cb2?.call(0, 5, 6));     // cant invoke cb1() or cb2()
  console.log(cb1?.apply(0, [5, 6]));  // but you can use call or apply
  console.log(cb2?.apply(0, [5, 6]));  // where first parameter can be any value
}

x(a, b); // 11 11 11 11

class C {
  public f?: callback;
  public setF() {
    this.f = (x, y) => {
      return x + y;
    };
  }
}
const c = new C(); // same with objects
c.setF();
console.log(c?.f?.call(c, 2, 3)); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

For any one who come next. Another option is to use type casting.
like:

```
props = props as NativeProps
```

In my experience I used a context who return a Partial type object and i needed to do type casting to overcome the undefined error. like:

```
const {setSomething} = useContext(SomePartialContext) as MyContextType
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax that helped solve this issue for me.

Different ways of getting a solution:

```
search.prop('onSearch')!('text' as unknown)
search.prop('onSearch')!({} as unknown)
search.prop('onSearch')!({} as any)
```

The key portion is: `!({} as any}`

Answer (score 0):

In-case you are here because of `ts(2722)` error not because of the above question.

You can use [JavaScript's Optional method chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax here