# How to remove TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function looking like this

```
let bcInst;
if(props.onBoundsChanged){
    bcInst = kakao.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed',()=>{
        props.onBoundsChanged(map); //I get error here
    })
}
```

props interface looking like below

```
interface IMapProps{
    mapId?: string;
    longitude: number;
    latitude: number;
    level:number;
    onBoundsChanged?:{
        (map:any) : void
    }
}
```

Even if I am checking for props.onBoundsChanged in an if statement, I am getting TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. error at the position I am using props.onBoundsChanged. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript is saying your `onBoundsChanged` might be undefined because you have defined it as an optional `(?)` property in the interface IMapProps:

```
onBoundsChanged?: {}
```

Your check for `onBoundsChanged` for a `truthy` value is correct, but the event listener will be invoked at a later time, which means `onBoundsChanged` might be undefined like @basarat specified. You can avoid this error by using one of these *inside your listener.*

Check for truthy value before calling `onBoundsChanged`

```
if(props.onBoundsChanged) onBoundsChanged(map)
```

Use *optional chaining* `?.` operator to access `onBoundsChanged`

```
props?.onBoundsChanged(map)
```

**Some useful learning resources:**

You can read more about `truthy` values from the MDN here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

More about the `optional chaining ?.` operator here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue as below. In my case, my code is

```
 handleClick={(p: ActionFieldClickParam) =>
        this.props.handleClick({ p, index })
 }
```

then, I solved by adding '?.' and changed function call like `this.props.handleClick?.({ p, index })`

In your case, you should add next to the call function:

```
props.onBoundsChanged?.(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you event listener might be invoked *much later* than you have done the check, TypeScript is complaining

## Fix

Store the reference that TypeScript knows to be valid e.g.

```
let bcInst;
if(props.onBoundsChanged){
    const {onBoundsChanged} = props; // STORE
    bcInst = kakao.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed',()=>{
        onBoundsChanged(map); // OKAY
    })
}
```

Alternatively move the check inside the listener.