# Conditional type based on value of variable in a class (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm creating a generic class named `Loadable<T>`, with two fields. One is named `state`, and contains the current state of the loadable resource. The second is named `data`, and contains the value of the loadable resource.

`state` is defined as `"loading" | "loaded" | "error"`, and I'd like to type of `data` to change based on the current value of `state`.

For example, if `state` is `"loading"`, then `data` should be `null`. I cannot figure out the syntax to do this.

I've created a `type` named `LoadableState<T, U>` which is defined as:

```
    type LoadableState<T, U> =
        T extends "loaded" ? U :
        T extends "loading" ? null :
        T extends "error" ? string :
        never;
```

Where `T` passed must be the type `"loaded" | "loading" | "error"`.

This part works, but trying to define `data` from this does not.

```
export class Loadable<T> {
    public state: "loaded" | "loading" | "error" = "loading";

    public data: LoadableState<state, T>;
    //                         ^^^^^ Cannot find name 'state`
}
```

TypeScript throws the following error: `Cannot find name 'state'`

---

Other things I've tried:

```
public data: LoadableState<this.state, T>;
// Duplicate identified 'state'

public data: LoadableState<typeof this.state, T>;
// Cannot find name 'this'

public data: LoadableState<typeof state, T>;
// Cannot find name 'state'

public data: state extends "loaded" ? T :
    state extends "loading" ? null :
    state extends "error" ? string :
    never;
// Cannot find name 'state'
```

---

I'm not sure if this is actual possible. If this isn't, is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: You could be interested in this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I don't think there's a way (or at least not a clean way) to have the type of one class property to depend on the current value of another property.

You're better off combining both these properties into a single object:

```
type LoadState<T> = {
    state: "loading",
} | {
    state: "loaded",
    data: T
} | {
    state: "error",
    data: string; // or maybe 'message'
}

export class Loadable<T> {
    state: LoadState<T> = { state: "loading" }
}
```

Though the class wrapper isn't actually very useful here, you might consider not using the class at all.

When using this type, Typescript will enforce that you check the `state` before trying to access data:

```
function handleLoadState<T>(loadState: LoadState<T>) {
   loadState.data // ERROR, can't access data, since it might not exist
   if(loadState.state === "loaded")
       loadState.data // okay
   }
}
```

This pattern is called a [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and is quite commonly used in Typescript.

Comment: This is a great solution to solve this problem. Thank you!