# TypeScript interface matching a function and its arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a few functions with different argument signatures:

```
function foo(a: number) {...}
function bar(a: string) {...}
...
```

I need to create a TypeScript interface (or type) to capture the following:

```
interface MyInterface {
   method: typeof foo | typeof bar;
   args: Parameters<foo | bar>;
}
```

Such that if the `method` supplied is foo, TypeScript will complain if `args` is `[string]`, as it should expect `[number]` for foo. Likewise, if `method` is bar, `args` should be of type `[string]`.

So `method` could be any one of the functions I supply to the interface, and `args` should be the corresponding arguments for that function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use generics.  Make `MyInterface` a generic that takes a type argument.

```js
// Generic interface that requires a type argument
interface MyInterface<T> {
  method: (arg: T) => void,
  args: T
}

// Your functions
const foo = (thing: string) => { console.log(thing) }
const bar = (thing: number) => { console.log(thing) }

// Object of shape MyInterface must take a type argument
// That type argument must satisfy foo:
const makeAGoodArgument: MyInterface<string> = {
  method: foo,
  args: 'whatever'
}

const makeAnotherGoodArgument: MyInterface<number> = {
  method: bar,
  args: 80
}

const makeABadArgument: MyInterface<string> = {
  method: foo,
  args: 800 // <---- this errors
}
```

### [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYFcC2FwDOAPACoB8yA3gFDLJ5gAWA9gCYBcyAFHJpyQEpkAXgoA3ZsFYAaWsl4YC-agF9q1BMxAEwyGM2YjuTUBk46opoaKrJN25gBsIAOkfMMXEyAxC19nWQAI14jL0ZTThBcIOhrCko7LQInV3dPb19kNQ1k3Rw4AGsIVABxA1Z0bDxwTircfDBiC1MKYSo5BhYOPQNZOgUlZAByAHdGOEgxaGHVdQD8opKQZiZocrZ6mrA6zAbCImicWKg2jroutk4QqH75TCGADgAGOdztReLUACE4Sr3trtqo1mmBLD4zjQLhAmFdesw7oNOC9XiogA)

If you don't like having to declare type arguments every time you create an object, you can do it up front:

```
type MyInterfaces = MyInterface<string> | MyInterface<number>

const makeAGoodArgument: MyInterfaces = { ... }
```

You will achieve the same result.  It requires a bit more interface and type definitions up front, but once you get to writing your objects, you don't have to supply a type argument with every object you write.

If you were hoping for an interface structure that would infer this for you without a type argument, I would echo [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027601/12010984): I don't think there's a way (or at least not a clean way) to have the type of one class property to depend on the current value of another property.