# A Typescript interface that allows one of 2 optional keys or none but not both

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define a Typescript `interface` which allows one of 2 optional keys in an object or **none of them**, but **not both**?

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
const example1 = { foo: 'some string' }; //should pass - can have only "foo: string"

const example2 = { bar: 42 }; // should pass - can have only "bar: number"

const example3 = {}; // should pass - both foo and bar are optional

const example4 = { foo: 'some string', bar: 42 }; // should throw a Typescript error - can't have both foo and bar simultaneously;
```

PS. solution should be an `interface` and not a `type` since in my use-case it `extends` another `interface`

Comment: There is no way to do this relying only on Typescript's `Interface`s.

Comment: It shouldn't, there is no sound way of enforcing that on call point / caller point. Why not use 2 different interfaces? Sounds a lot like they are two different concepts.

Comment: @Mic - these are 2 keys in a options object passed to a function - both are valid - but they just can't co-exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`type` is isomorphic to `interface` and you can join these two constructs. Below implementation by type union and intersection, also added example interface to show it works well, `&` is equivalent to `extends`. Consider:

```
interface OtherInterface {
    field?: string
}
type Example = ({
    foo: string
    bar?: never
} | {
    foo?: never
    bar: number
} | {
    [K in any]: never
}) & OtherInterface

const example1: Example = { foo: 'some string' }; // ok

const example2: Example = { bar: 42 }; // ok

const example3: Example = {}; // ok

const example4: Example = { foo: 'some string', bar: 42 }; // error
```

The solution is verbose, but match your need. Some explanations:

- `bar?: never` is used in order to block possibility to have a value which has such field
- `& OtherInterface` has exactly the same result as `extends OtherInterface`
- `{[K in any]: never}` - represents empty object `{}`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=20&ssc=68&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJgBbQJLmvJZAbwFgAoZS5GYCAGwBMB+ALmQGcwpQBzcgX3JgAngAcUAUQAecALai6KALzIAFKQpUYAe21tO3EH02UARnCitkICADdoA5AB9i5KtV1Wb9qG6rmoNhAAV1lTBzJ+Z1cTZABtAGlkUGQ4EGEAXSC7CP4ASmQAMjRMHDxYRAhycgRtEE5kCBl5RQBGNmk5BWViDz1kAHJ2bVkUA14B5H4AbmQAejnkbQBrarJa+rBG5u6AJg6dxWQVImQAtgAWXanZhaXVshq6hqauxQBmA7eeohn5xZWaw2L0OEAuXxaPz6bCGIzGXAmABozhZLtc-ndoFBtFAgA)

Comment: Sorry by mistake wrote interface as `type`, fixed now

Comment: Heya, found an error with this and was hoping you could help out, if you have `{ field: 'test' }` without `foo` or `bar` it errors, ideally an empty object would pass but so would one with `field` and no other values. Link to TS playground too long to post so will add additional comment.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJgBbQJLmvJZAbwFgAoZS5GYCAGwBMB+ALmQGcwpQBzcgX3JgAngAcUAUQAecALai6KALzIAFKQpUYAe21tO3EH02UARnCitkICADdoA5AB9i5KtV1Wb9qG6rmoNhAAV1lTBzJ+Z1cTZABtAGlkUGQ4EGEAXSC7CP4ASmQAMjRMHDxYRAhycgRtEE5kCBl5RQBGNmk5BWViDz1kAHJ2bVkUA14B5H4AbmQAejnkbQBrarJa+rBG5u6AJg6dxWQVImQAtgAWXanZhaXVshq6hqauxQBmA7ee05n5xZWaw2L0OEAuXxaPz6bCGIzGXAmABozhZLtc-ndoFBtL5HutnltXpCAKwQ7rHXo0egMGGQTgDZHnZBXG7-e5Agnbb4ANjJRxO1FojFpEHprMxUGxuPIQA