# Define an object with an optional amount of keys, but at least ONE key

Tags: typescript

How can I achieve this ?

```
type Fruit = "apple" | 'banana' | 'coconut'

type FruitCollection = { [f in Fruit]?: number }

const validFruitCollection: FruitCollection = { apple: 1, coconut: 2 } 

const emptyCollectionShouldNotPass: FruitCollection = {} // I don't want typescript to let this pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)

Comment: This answer is exactly what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/4467208

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=120#

Comment: Murat the difference is here that in these examples types are presize, here we have very loose type. It means we cannot pick what exactly should stay

Answer (score 5):

You can intersect the type with all optional members with a union of all properties, where all in each constituent of the union, one member is required. So basically you will have:

```
type WhatWeWant = {
    apple?: number | undefined;
    banana?: number | undefined;
    coconut?: number | undefined;
} & (
    | { apple: number; }
    | { banana: number; }
    | { coconut : number ;})
```

To get this type without writing it out we can use a mapped type:

```
type RequireOne<T> = T & { [P in keyof T]: Required<Pick<T, P>> }[keyof T]
type FruitCollection = RequireOne<{ [f in Fruit]?: number }>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=61&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8oByAI2wDtbtzSKBjAezZoWHIFgAofv1CQoAJQgBHZHAgB5GhAA8AFQB86KMqgAyKAG8oAbQAKUJDSgBrCCFYAzTQF0AXGMnSIAE0XGkzSyoANFDGquoAvobWtg7KjkLg0PDIwADCrPiEzMBIrBYY4lJIMvJKBoYO5rCIKI4A-K6cALaUEHBQ4aqCfBwAzqgAbtj4SJ7JKOmZENm5NK7jaRlZOXkaBrgEEK4AjMFsHFyuAEwdUAD0Z1CsllDdfagQTWCgk8uzAMoAFqwI+J4AcqxgMZsL1evMaospjNVhg9OFzpc2nB+EA)

The idea of the mapped type in `RequireOne` is to create union in the `WhatWeWant` type above (`T` will be the original type will al the optional properties). So what we do, in the mapped type is we take each property in `T` and type it as `Required<Pick<T, P>>`. This means for each key, we get a type that only contains that key, basically this type for the example:

```
{
  apple: { apple: number; }
  banana: { banana: number; }
  coconut: { coconut: number ;}
}
```

With this type, the matter of getting the union we want is just a matter with indexing `keyof T`, to get a union of all property types in our object.

Comment: @Lev added an explanation, let me know if you need more details

Comment: Many thanks. Trying to see if my knukle head gets it now.

Answer (score 4):

What we need is type which will exclude possibility of empty object. In order to achieve that we need utility type and value constructor. Consider:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | 'banana' | 'coconut'

type FruitCollection = { [f in Fruit]?: number }

// type which will exclude empty object
type NotEmpty<T> = {} extends T ? never : T

// value constructor
const makeFruitCollection = <T extends FruitCollection>(c: NotEmpty<T>) => c; 

// use cases
const validFruitCollection = makeFruitCollection({ apple: 1, coconut: 2 }) // ok 
const emptyCollectionShouldNotPass = makeFruitCollection({}) // error
```

Type `NotEmpty` is checking if our `T` which already pass all needs of `FruitCollection` is not empty object, if it is we get `never`, and there is no value of type `never` therefor using function with `{}` will not compile.

[The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=73#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8oByAI2wDtbtzSKBjAezZoWHICgfRIsRCgDCrfIWbAkrGuigBvKAG0AZlCRz4yYAF0A-AC4onALaUIcKAF8%20AejtQB0AO4ALJMzdQXSCVAgAD2Z8BAATaAhTMFAoVkoAKwgpfnBoADlWYABRaNAAHgAVAD55BWsAwOAIGjCAZyhCqH0TCAA3SyhjQr4OOtRTbABrCG1RcUlpWXkiyurahrHgMQlkqZpigApmY0ycvJAi4oBKdFLmAG4oXtl%20qDbsfCQwpZXJmRoMQZHXibWPzZKXAECDGACMABooGwOFxjAAmGynBxxIZQQC8G4AZHZuNDuURiIDe-1kAGU3KwEPgwnsAArYOoNL7DUbCZZ-KQA8rIxyWOCsKxYoA)

Comment: If you are using a function, then this is a good option, the usual problem with this solution is that the type itself does not require at least one property, so you can end up with variables that do not respect the constraint. But for function parameters it is a good, arguably simpler to understand solution :)

Comment: There is a built-in utility type: Exclude. Thus `NotEmpty<T>` can be rewritten as `Exclude<T, {}>`?