# Compile time check if typescript interface has one or more properties

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I need to find a way to **check** if a typescript interface has **one or more properties** (property names are unknown) **at compile time**.

So for example given the following definitions:

```
export type Cat = {};
export type Dog = { barking: boolean };
```

I need a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) `HasAnyProperties<T>` which will give me:

```
type catHasProperties = HasAnyProperties<Cat>;   // false   (because Cat is {})
type dogHasProperties = HasAnyProperties<Dog>;   // true    (because Dog has one or more properties)
```

To be clear **I do not want**:

- To use `Object.keys(obj).length`    (this is a runtime check)
- To [enforce or require one or more known properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/keyvault-certificates/requireatleastone?view=azure-node-latest). I only want to check.

This may seem like an odd request, but what I'm actually doing is first [filtering a type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199#issuecomment-379323872) after which I need to know if anything was left over. I then use that value to optionally add a new property on a mapped type. But that's the easy part!

The following attempts don't work:

```
// This always returns true
type HasAnyProperties<T> = T extends { [key: string]: any } ? true : false;
```

It would be a lot easier if I knew the names of the properties, but I don't.

My guess if this is possible is that it will look something like [RequireAtLeastOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/16940).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's as simple as this:

```
 export type HasAnyProperties<T> = {} extends T ? false : true;
```

At least for my case. If anyone with a similar need finds issues with this please comment or add a new answer.