# How to correctly define a type that is a merged intersection type of two other types?

Tags: typescript

I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510700/2891356) answer, but I don't want to use interfaces. There are several other answers on that page, but none are setup like mine.

I have the following,

```
type TMenuOptionBase = {
    id: string;
    text: string;
};
type TMenuOptionRoot = TMenuOptionBase & { onClick: (...params: any[]) => any };
type TMenuOptionParent = TMenuOptionBase & { submenu: TMenuOption[] };

export type TMenuOption = TMenuOptionRoot | TMenuOptionParent;
```

And I can define an object, such as,

```
const menuOptions = [
    {
        id: '1',
        text: 'Option 1',
        onClick: () => console.log('clicked 1'),
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        text: 'Option 2',
        submenu: [
            {
                id: '3',
                text: 'Option 3',
                onClick: () => console.log('clicked 3'),
            },
            {
                id: '4',
                text: 'Option 4',
                submenu: [
                    {
                        id: '5',
                        text: 'Option 5',
                        onClick: () => console.log('clicked 5'),
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
] as TMenuOption[]
```

The only problem with this setup, is that I can add a `submenu` *and* an `onClick` event. For instance, this should *not* be valid,

```
    {
        id: '1',
        text: 'Option 1',
        onClick: () => console.log('clicked 1'),
        submenu: [ . . . ]
    },
```

TS identifies both as of type `TMenuOption`, when it should identify them of type `TMenuOptionParent` and `TMenuOptionRoot`, respectively.

How can I get this to work properly?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=27&pln=8&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgshAdgVwPJmASwPaIEICGAztALxQDeAUAJCYAmAXFEcAE6aIDmA3LcBAAewZqw7c+AXz6hIsBCnRZcAJWzZgUcvCRoMOfMWgAySlFwBhADaYAxgGtmACgB0bsATYEAtkWYFEEABtAF0ASi0APigAkChpKlloHUV9XAAFTyRNbQU9ZUMSKFMKFmQAI29dZhT8g1D4viohMGw2TST5XSUDLS7UgrUNKAAffrqMrMRgJttcVigqgYMiPqCqKE3KDa3dhmYAcgBGA4AaHd3NgWFDntwoE-PLrcsbB2cI0mi5xCJsKwgLis2C4TgOtje9gg9AeBzCTy2kgRm2oz02+ygBwATGcLpdriJMXdEFAccjLkQKktkMx1mjLqj6WiMQcAMy4plogm3NIk9nkzmbV52RxQJyfb7zf6A4Gg8GQ6FQdnwvH0pGqtGMwVbFkAFg52q23KJvKg+oFgsplWqUDphueWvtzKYmIArAanVyhISDsSoO6LZ6hYhrCKPlEYgD2mCISLFe6VUHEYGmSEU7t1fS03j1SEYqtasTQlQgA)

I've also tried,

```
type TMenuOptionBase = {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    onClick: (...params: any[]) => any;
    submenu: TMenuOptionBase[];
};

type TMenuOptionParent = Omit<TMenuOptionBase, 'onClick'>;
type TMenuOptionRoot = Omit<TMenuOptionBase, 'submenu'>;

export type TMenuOption = TMenuOptionParent & TMenuOptionRoot;

const menuOption = {
    id: '1',
    text: 'Option 1',
    onClick: () => console.log('s'),
    submenu: []
} as TMenuOption;
```

But that didn't work either.

As per the comment from @ford04, I've tried the XOR method,

```
type TMenuOptionBase = {
    id: string;
    text: string;
};

type TMenuOption = TMenuOptionBase & (
        | { onClick: (...params: any[]) => void; submenu?: never }
        | { onClick?: never; submenu: TMenuOptionBase[] }
    )
```

But TS doesn't throw an error when I have,

```
const menuOption = {
    id: '1',
    text: 'Option 1'
} as TMenuOption
```

Comment: The second variant in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617060/5669456) (XOR) should be able to do, what you want. Alternatively, you could define `TMenuOption` as a discriminated union type with extra (string) discriminant property.

Comment: Please see updated post

Comment: Drop the type assertion (that's a way of suppressing type checks) and instead use an explicit type - [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgshAdgVwPJmASwPaIEICGAztALxQDeAUFLVJgCYBcURwATpogOYDcNdYBAAewFm049+AX35VQkWAhTosuKOXhI0GHPmLQAZFAAUAunQA+lKLgDCAG0wBjANYsTAOm9gC7AgC2RCwEiCAA2gC6AJQaAHxQAG7YjLysyABGAdoA-CyIEIkQ7FDS5hZQ1hS2iI4urnlQBUXsaUSZ2SgsWiq6uIQkUaXl0VRUzrhsUJ06aojdyrN6GpTljCwA5ACMGwA05UKim6rLO-sW7VnaLFHndAD09zV1bh6xpAkUZdJAA).