# How to ensure two elements either exist together in an object or neither exists at all?

Tags: typescript

I've come across some answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist) one, but the wording of my question doesn't return relevant results.

Consider the following:

```
type TNode = {
    data: {
        id: string;
    } | {
        tree: boolean;
        treeName: string;
    }

}

const nodes: TNode[] = [
    {
        data: {
            id: '1',
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: '2',
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: '3',
            tree: true,
            treeName: 'retrieval',
        }
    }
]
```

This approach doesn't have TS complain, but it's not what I'm looking for. If I remove the property `treeName: 'retrieval'` from the last object in `nodes`, it should complain, saying that I've included `tree` but I'm missing `treeName`.

How can I achieve this?

## Edit

The accepted answer worked for me, and so did the following approach, which I ended up using because I didn't want to add extra properties to my objects,

```
interface INodeBase {
    id: string
}

interface INodeWithProps extends INodeBase {
    tree: boolean;
    treeName: string;
}

interface INodeWithOutProps extends INodeBase {
    tree?: never;
    treeName?: never;
}

type TNode = {
    data: INodeWithProps | INodeWithOutProps
}

const nodes: TNode[] = [
    {
        data: {
            id: '1',
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: '2',
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: '3',
            tree: true,
            treeName: 'retrieval',
        }
    },
    {
        data: {
            id: '4',
            tree: 'true', // error, 'treeName' is missing
        }
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simplify the example a little:

```
type Node = Leaf | Tree;
type Leaf = {
  id: string
}
type Tree = {
  tree: boolean,
  treeName: string
}
```

Then, we are allowed to do:

```
const o = {
  id: '3',
  foo: 43,
  bar: false
}
const n: Node = o; // just fine: o has all properties a Leaf needs
```

In particular, note that we are generally allowed to provide arbitrary excess properties.

The same happens if excess properties would match another type in the union:

```
const o = {
  id: '3',
  tree: true,
}
const n: Node = o; // just fine: o has all properties a Leaf needs
```

TypeScript performs excess property checking only in a few special cases. The most common one is an object literal immediately assigned to an object type:

```
const o: Tree = {
  id: '3', // error: excess property not declared by Tree
  tree: true,
  treeName: 'retrieval',
}
```

Given this, one might reasonably expect that excess property checking also applies to union types:

```
const o: Node = {
  id: '3',
  tree: true,
  treeName: 'retrieval',
}
```

However, that is [only the case for discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5-rc/), which yours is not.

Therefore, you probably want to change your definition to:

```
type Leaf = {
  id: string,
  tree: false,
}
type Tree = {
  tree: true,
  treeName: string
}
```

Then, the value of the `tree` property tells TypeScript which type it should be type checking against, while enabling excess properties to be rejected in immediately assigned object literals:

```
const o: Node = {
  id: '3', // error: property id does not exist on Tree
  tree: true,
  treeName: 'retrieval'
}      

const q: Node = {
  tree: true,
  // error: property treeName is missing
}

const x: Node = {
  id: '4',
  tree: false,
  treeName: 'retrieval' // error: property treeName does not exist on Leaf
}
```

Comment: I applaud your approach at this breakdown explanation. Kind regards.