# Conditional props depending on props

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface BlockCtaDoubleProps
{
    subheadline: string;
    headline: string;
    button: string;
    link: string;
    subheadlineLeft?: string;
    headlineLeft?: string;
    buttonLeft?: string;
    image?: string;
    alt?: string;
}
```

`Image` & `alt` can only exit if there's no `...Left` props and vice versa. How can I make this clear with interfaces to prevent disparities?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist). It explains how to conditionally allow either one of the many or at absolutely either one out many property to be present in interface.