# Create a type that allow one member within an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using Typescript 3.9.x

Supposed I have an interface:

```js
interface mytype {
    foo: Foo
    bar: Bar
    baz: Baz
}
```

I want to achieve a `OnlyOneOfType<T>` type that allows only one member within the interface.

Such that:

```js
const test1: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = {foo: 'FOO'}; // PASSES
const test2: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = {bar: 'BAR'}; // PASSES

const test3: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = {foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR'}; // fails
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Are you looking for a `Set`?

Comment: I can give you a straightforward solution that would handle your sample cases but would also accept objects where the unwanted properties are `undefined`, e.g. `{foo: 'FOO', bar: undefined}`. Rejecting these will be a lot harder.

Comment: @Oblosys I prefer one where the undefined property are rejected but I'd like to see the straightforward solution too.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow, it might just be possible. The `RequireOnlyOne` solution has the same problem as my simple one in that it also accepts `{foo: 'FOO', bar: undefined}`.

Comment: @Terry, please note that asking for `OnyOneOfType<mytype >` to be `{foo: Foo} | {bar: Bar} | {baz: Baz}` is not the same as asking for it to allow only one member (see [this q/a](//stackoverflow.com/questions/46370222/typescript-a-b-allows-combination-of-both)).  Which one do you want?  The former is straightforward; the latter is less so but still reasonable. Both will allow `{foo: "FOO", bar: undefined}`. There is no specific type in TypeScript which will allow `{foo: "FOO"}` and reject `{foo: "FOO", bar: undefined}`. You can use generics to get closer, but I doubt it's worth the effort.

Comment: which, btw, the former is `type OnlyOneOfType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends unknown ? { [Key in K]: T[K] } : never; }[keyof T]`

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. I've edited my question/post now. I'm seeking the latter. The post you've linked was very useful.

Comment: @Federkun is there some advantage to that over `{[K in keyof T]: Pick<T, K>}[keyof T]`?  I'm not sure why you are doing a `T[K] extends unknown` check in there, and `Pick` is homomorphic (so `{readonly a?: string}` in will be `{readonly a?: string}` out and not `{a: string | undefined}`)

Comment: None, im just bad at typescript

Comment: @jcalz Are you certain about that? Both solutions seem to infer `{a?: string | undefined}`, with the `?` and also an extra `| undefined`. They also incorrectly include `undefined` in the union. You can avoid the latter with a conditional definition that remaps the keys: https://tsplay.dev/wQAeAw (requires TypeScript v4.1 though).

Comment: @Terry My idea from last night made no sense, I thought about enumerating all configurations of `never` props, but having the bare singleton objects in the union means objects with multiple keys won't be rejected, so it seems the `undefined`s can't be avoided.

Comment: @Oblosys heh no I guess you're right.  I suppose having `K in keyof T` earlier is enough to maintain homomorphicity (that's not a word) with `P in K` later.  I didn't realize that.  (Including `undefined` in the union happens even if it's not homomorphic though)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this type?

```js
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> &
    {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>;
    }[Keys];

type OnlyOneOfType<T> = RequireOnlyOne<T, keyof T>

interface mytype {
    foo: 'FOO'
    bar: 'BAR'
    baz: 'BAZ'
}

const test1: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = { foo: 'FOO' }; // PASSES
const test2: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = { bar: 'BAR' }; // PASSES
const test3: OnlyOneOfType<mytype> = { foo: 'FOO', bar: 'BAR' }; // FAILS
```

That's the same as KPD's answer in this question...[url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)