# Typescript ambient warnings always wants every key in type union when using method parameter type

Tags: typescript, union-types

[Click here for StackBlitz Example](https://typescript-xdlhsg.stackblitz.io)

**Problem:**

Why can't I have **Foo** without **Bar** or more specifically how do I change this to allow either or both, but complain about anything else?

TS Warning confusing me....

[image]

**index.ts**

[image]

**service.ts**

[image]

**serviceConfig.ts**

[image]

Presumably my Service Method - **dataWithValidKeys: { [key in validKeys]: any }** is wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)

Comment: Thanks Joe, this did help steer me towards utility types documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  "Partial" was missing...

> Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

[See all utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

[image]

Voila!

[image]

[Working version](https://typescript-8qzt9x.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Just be aware that it allows none of the properties as well.