# How to create a RequireOnlyOne nested type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've seen this code snippet a lot:

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
& {
    [K in Keys]-?:
        Required<Pick<T, K>>
        & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>
}[Keys]
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist) you can find the question from where I took it.

It works, however, I have this structure:

```
export interface MenuItems {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  };
  anotherFirstLevel: {
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two'],
    oneMoreSecondLevel: null
  };
}
```

I need to apply `RequireOnlyOne` for the first and the second levels, but I can't figure what to change on the type `RequireOnlyOne` so it works for each firstLevel keys but also with secondLevel keys. As it is right now I can select only one firstLevel but multiple secondLevels of that firstLevel.

I also tried to compose a new type with an object which key could be `RequireOnlyOne<keyof MenuItems>` and a value that uses also `RequireOnlyOne` for the values, but couldn't make it.

Example of what I want, calling the desired type as `customType`:

```
const workingObject: customType = {
  firstLevel: { // Just one property of the first level
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two'] // Just one property of the second level
  };
}

const errorObject: customType = {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  };
  anotherFirstLevel: { // Should not work as I am including 2 properties for the first level
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  };
}

const anotherErrorObject: customType = {
  anotherFirstLevel: {
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two'],
    oneMoreSecondLevel: null // Should not work neither as I am including 2 properties for second level
  };
}
```

The type should throw an error if the object has more than one first level property, and/or more than one second level property. With the proposed `RequireOnlyOne` type I can achieve that but just for the first level, but I need the same effect for first **and** second level.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean only for forst and second level, please provide an example of what you expect

Comment: @captain-yossarian sure, I have the interface `MenuItems` with nested objects. I want to create a type that allows only **one** property of each level.

Comment: SOrry, I don't see any difference between two `customType` variables. Please provide your question with this example

Comment: @captain-yossarian example added directly to the question, hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to change `RequireOnlyOne` type but I know how to create new type.

```js
export interface MenuItems {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  };
  anotherFirstLevel: {
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two']
    oneMoreSecondLevel: null
  };
}

type Primitives = string | number | boolean | null | undefined | bigint | symbol

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Transform<Obj, Keys extends keyof Obj = keyof Obj, Result = never> =
  StrictUnion<
    Keys extends string ? { // #1
      [Key in Keys]:
      Key extends keyof Obj
      ? (Obj[Key] extends Primitives
        ? Obj[Key]
        : (Obj[Key] extends any[]
          ? Obj[Key]
          : Transform<Obj[Key], keyof Obj[Key], Obj[Key]>)
      )
      : never
    } : Result>


type CustomType = Transform<MenuItems>

const workingObject: CustomType = {
  firstLevel: { // Just one property of the first level
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two'] // Just one property of the second level
  },
}


const errorObject: CustomType = {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  },
  anotherFirstLevel: { // Should not work as I am including 2 properties for the first level
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two']
  },
}

const anotherErrorObject: CustomType= {
  anotherFirstLevel: {
    anotherSecondLevel: ['one', 'two'],
    oneMoreSecondLevel: null // Should not work neither as I am including 2 properties for second level
  },
}
```

**`Transform`** - is a main utility type. Recursively iterates over keys. 1# `Keys extends string` - this line makes sure that that `Keys is distributet`. It means that whole code which goes after this line will be applied to each key.  Please see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) for more info.

I have also added `Obj[Key] extends any[]` - because you don't want (I suppose) to iterate though arrays keys.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWWCQFcBJVAWwGc4BvAKDjnQSipgBlgA3YAGwBcdRkzhVg2CEgAmXXoLgBtAORTgygDRxlMAO4RlAXREBfANwjMSCDAAWaAGKt2c-kIai4Vm-agBlCSlZHjclVSR1LR19IxEmNXxoYADJGVcFEj4%20UwsTenoYAE8wPAAFKAQKBBgEXhoAXjEYCqQAczgAHzgSCgAjNE64XogIPmArQcy%20QeIZYBYI6UHehFbkeC6qQr7R-KKSuABVJAQpAGlgQqoAHgAVAD44Rtu4UFQZGheAfjgAa0uIOg4C8hBFeFALAB6SFwbBQYDSao0VoQYA0GAQOC2GAwMBUATQ9g4X4QcHoPgQXQAOkkFEhAEdiGialIqJCAGwAVgAHAAGTns3m8yH7YAAWlmpyQYusMDF2Hs2F%20yFaYvQ0DFoFwVCoYrAUAgJVgCDRAGIrFRdGgxVy%20ZyAOycgDMBWKeD8zQQ2BgxylAAl%20Ea7lpbgBBLKPeoiF5vIjSGhWQoiH4vABkcFKmGNmD41wASoEoNJrgBREDYPjEaTAa6%2086XG5hiNaf6FQHA%205aMFoe6PUEhCF7N1wD0Vb11pB3SMjz3jk5SAN8IO3EP3IcHW5QC3qqAUa4AeV6ACstBcrq8QO9438AUDD0enje23fj1oC1RiHx4I1u1BIyJRy9H150nOI4DPGhYw%20JoWnaH4PE8JQz0QJBwIbQwBDAphkKg69W3be8sLgH4AAp70UM9DAvK8aHKSpqlqNEiKYH5yMo5i4CEMjjwoy4qNwhMkEKRRjEQxDWJ49ixM8IRN23aA9zYviW1vOAlMKQwtHUwx7gASiI-SxP7cEwJMTi4HfT8YDXdc8AAYWIdgIAoW5h2eLckCoHc90IEhyGAagbNSdg4H0KBlTae8JBgIQHKcly3OEJgWDYTgQgUWg4GhOAAClHPgNQ4H1Q00CKOB2zsPAUpCsZ5DA8RUmCeQhBUNRNG0PQDCo7K8pCwriqNMqKvsMRAhkOBav4UwNHoPJ8mC%20A0ANKAou9WL8uc1yDkaBDqrS5qktEBqgnSFrwkiDqYlEuATBmphvEqqAnFS066CymE-FsCBPyWWVQugX4vBoUgvAoFCKyrFU4AAJiKg1BpNGgdzgSrmGceBJuyTwHt8FITvSs62qiTrYiYW7Zvm1l4BxtASygZbVpiuA4oxBKSh2yxZV8Z6XAJw77q5tA8bSPnWoidroi6u7RASJJhaa0Ipnekcvp%207obH%208LumAapfCBuAQcwMHkAhxE2hhuGSuNNFmGgUbGom9LptmoA)

Comment: Yeap, it's working just as I needed, thank you so much @captain-yossarin!

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's a quite complex question and I'd recommend looking for alternatives and refactor the code.

Otherwise, you might find this helpful:

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> &
  {
    [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>;
  }[Keys];

type RequireOnlyOneUnion<T, Keys extends KeysOfUnion<T> = KeysOfUnion<T>> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> &
  {
    [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>;
  }[Keys];

export interface MenuItems {
  firstLevel: {
    secondLevel: ["one", "two"];
  };
  anotherFirstLevel: {
    anotherSecondLevel: ["one", "two"];
    oneMoreSecondLevel: null;
  };
}

type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

const x: RequireOnlyOne<MenuItems, keyof MenuItems> = { firstLevel: { secondLevel: ["one", "two"] } };

// ok
const a: RequireOnlyOneUnion<MenuItems[keyof typeof x], KeysOfUnion<MenuItems[keyof typeof x]>> = {
  anotherSecondLevel: ["one", "two"],
};
// error
const b: RequireOnlyOneUnion<MenuItems[keyof typeof x], KeysOfUnion<MenuItems[keyof typeof x]>> = {
  secondLevel: ["one", "two"],
  anotherSecondLevel: ["one", "two"],
};
```

Comment: It shows an error for `keyof typeof x`: `Type 'symbol' cannot be used as an index type.`

Comment: oh, right, I updated the answer

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: works for me with ts v4.3.5