# Setting defaults without making all attributes optional

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have 2 interfaces.

```js
interface ItemGroup {
    itemDefaults: Partial<Item>
    items: Item[]
}

interface Item {
    price?: number
    size?: string
}
```

I want to make sure the attribute is provided in default or the Item. Its fine if both are provided, but at least one should be required.

```
//Should be Valid
[{
    "itemDefaults": {
        "price": 10,
        "size": "L"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "size": "M"
        }
    ]
}]

//Should be Invalid as both itemDefaults and Item is missing size
[{
    "itemDefaults": {
        "price": 10
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "price": 12
        }
    ]
}]
```

Is there a way to enforce something like this in TypeScript?

Comment: Isn't this answer what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/3739087

Comment: No. Its not about x or y property of the same or extended interfaces. Here there are 2 distinct interfaces like a CollectionGroup and the group has a collection of items.

Comment: `items` is an array. what if one `item` contains an attribute and another one dont. Is it valid or not?

Comment: Its fine to have all items with same attributes. One doesn't need to be different from the other, as long as these items include all the required attributes which haven't been specified in the itemDefaults.