# Check if an object is not empty in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have an interface like the following:

```
interface Cat {
  age? : number
  name? : string
}
```

with the following scenario:

```
function getAge(cat: Cat) {
  // ...
}

const catWithAge = getAge({}) // this is ok according the Cat interface
```

What I would like to do is the function `getAge` not to accept an empty object.

I would like to have at least one key passed in the object (doesn't matter which one).

What should I change in order to achieve this?

Comment: See the answer to the other question, code example looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m35KAw)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist