# Only one option can be non-null in case class

Tags: scala

I have a case class with two options

```scala
case class MyClass(
  first: Option[String] = None,
  second: Option[Boolean] = None
)
```

Is there a way in Scala to specify at the type level that both `first` and `second` can't both be set? So if `MyClass.second.isDefined` then `MyCLass.first` must be `None` and vice versa, or both can be `None`.

This [is possible in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617060).

Comment: Instead of two `Option` properties, rather have a single `Either` one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez so you're saying this is not possible? What if I have 3 (or more) options of 3 different types, of which only 1 can be set?

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you have more fields then a custom ADT is usually the best way to model this.

Comment: Well, **Scala 3** has union types and safer nulls so you may combine both to emulate the **typescript** solution. But note that is different from what you asked, still in **typescript** there is no way to say that a single type will only have one set value, rather you mix multiple different types into one... which is not conceptually different from the custom ADT that I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about this (the following code is for scala3, but it is easy to implement in scala2):

```
scala> @annotation.implicitNotFound("Need (None, Some) or (Some, None), found (${F}, ${S})")
     | trait Cons[F, S]
     |
     | object Cons:
     |   given Cons[Some[String], None.type]  = new Cons {}
     |   given Cons[None.type, Some[Boolean]] = new Cons {}
     |
     | case class MyClass[F <: Option[String], S <: Option[Boolean]](first: F, second: S)(using c: Cons[F, S])

scala> val m1 = MyClass(None, Some(true))
val m1: MyClass[None.type, Some[Boolean]] = MyClass(None,Some(true))

scala> val m2 = MyClass(Some(""), None)
val m2: MyClass[Some[String], None.type] = MyClass(Some(),None)

scala> val m3 = MyClass(None, None)
-- Error: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |val m3 = MyClass(None, None)
  |                            ^
  |                            Need (None, Some) or (Some, None), found (None.type, None.type)
1 error found

scala> val m4 = MyClass(Some(""), Some(false))
-- Error: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |val m4 = MyClass(Some(""), Some(false))
  |                                       ^
  |                                       Need (None, Some) or (Some, None), found (Some[String], Some[Boolean])
1 error found
```

Comment: It is really worth it all that complexity over a simple ADT like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/efhzgcFOSymnC6xPyB1mRQ? Also, the ADT is easily extensible this typeclass not so much.

Comment: I read this answer as "No."