# How to let typescript know the variable must be a string, but not undefine without faking?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `state`, `interface` , and a `function` that process the API data

- `const [series, setSeries] = useState<ISeries[]>([])`

---

```
export interface ITicket {
  status?: string
  status_desc?: string
  keyword_language?: string
}

interface ISeries {
  colorByPoint: boolean
  data: {
    name: string
    y: number
    status: string | undefined
    keyword_language: string | undefined
  }[]
}
```

---

function that process the api Data

```
function trans(series: ITicket[]) {

  const data = series.map(s => {

    return {
**//api only reuturn either s.status_desc or s.keyword_language, only one** 
      name: s.status_desc ? s.status_desc : s.keyword_language,
      y: s.ticket_count,
      status: s?.status,
      keyword_language: s?.keyword_language,

    }
  })

  return [
    {
      colorByPoint: true,
      data,
    },
  ]
}
```

---

In the `function` that process the API data, I am checking what value was passed in order to set the `name` property.

```
    return {
**//api only reuturn either s.status_desc or s.keyword_language, only one** 
      name: s.status_desc ? s.status_desc : s.keyword_language,
```

---

But then I get a TypeScript compilor error that it is not assignable since `name` must be a `string`. Now there is chance that it can be `undefined`.

Question:

I am sure that API will pass either `s.status_desc` or `s.keyword_language` as a `string`. So name **will** get a string value to assign.

I dont want to change the type for `name` to `string | undefined`

I don't want to use TypeScript ignore (`@ts-ignore`) to by pass the error.

How can I get rid of the error without faking?

bear in mind: in the interface, I cant change the type of  `status_desc` and `keyword_language` in order to bypass it because API could either pass me one. So I have to keep the type as `undefined` for both cases

Comment: What about casting with `as` ?

Comment: This just solve the typescript issue and make the code less readable because we don't get why this was added as it will never reach the last empty string value. I propose a comment to explain why we string cast `name`

Comment: Note that there is nothing in the code that prevents both `status_desc` *and* `keyword_language` from being undefined; your ternary won't solve that. I suggest using the nullish coalescing operator: `name: s.status_desc ?? s.keyword_language ?? ""` unless you know your service will always return one or the other. Note that it is possible to defined one or the other as undefined: see [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40510611/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may cast it like this:

```
name: (s.status_desc || s.keyword_language) as string,
```

The understanding of the || here is a bit different from traditional understanding.

for your reference:
[JavaScript OR (||) variable assignment explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation/3088498#3088498)

Comment: Thanks! This explain the part I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just cast the variable and add a comment like so:

```
{
  // Cast because server will always serv a string for at least one of the two
  name: (s.status_desc || s.keyword_language) as string,
}
```

Comment: let say, the s.status_desc was not returned, and only s.keyword_language returned.
Then (s.status_desc || s.keyword_language) become true..... s.status_desc is underfine and keyword have sth
, Will it become a true-false statement?

Comment: But I will to assign a value of string instead of yes/no 1/0

Comment: what do you think this kind of problem is classified as javascript problem or typescript problem ?

Comment: @Sergey Sosunov explained why

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: `name: s.status_desc || s.keyword_language || ""`

console.log(null || undefined || "" || "asd" || ""); will print "asd"

```
return {
    name: s.status_desc || s.keyword_language || "",
    y: s.ticket_count,    
    status: s.status,
    keyword_language: s?.keyword_language,
}
```

So if by any chance both fields are null or undefined - your code will not fail with error trying to access null field `name` (it will be an empty string)

Or you can use `Non-Null Assertion Operator !`:

Considered as a bad practice but can help anyway.

```
name: s.status_desc! || s.keyword_language!
```

Comment: Is there are name to call such sytanx? :Simplest way: name: s.status_desc || s.keyword_language || ""

Comment: Not sure if that syntax has a name, but here is an explanation about what is it and how it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/3088498/5767872

Answer (score 0):

Basically you may simply cast it.

as string.

Then typescript, you may think of it as compiler check, will see it as string