# Typescript require one of two properties to exist with nested property

Tags: typescript

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist), but the key difference is that I want to use nested attribute:

Imagine following TS interfaces:

```
export interface Nested {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
}

export interface Parent {
  nested?: Nested;
  c?: string;
}
```

I want to enforce that exactly one of `c` or `nested.a` exists. Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: There's numerous answers on this in the very question you linked, what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPRLKN) meet your needs when tested against your use cases?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @Etheryte - I tried using `RequireAtLeastOne` approach from one of the answers, but TypeScript doesn't allow me to list nested attributes like `RequireAtLeastOne<Parent, 'c' | 'nested.a'>`.

Comment: @jcalz - I think that works, thanks! Although I would prefer to reuse defined `Nested` interface, without having to redefine it. I guess it shouldn't be hard though, using Pick/Omit

Comment: The example is so minimal that `Pick`/`Omit` is definitely not worth it.  I could mention in the answer that you could always programmatically generate these types from `Nested` if you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, `Parent` must be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) representing the different ways to meet your constraint.  Essentially either `nested.a` is present and `c` is absent, or `nested.a` is absent and `c` is present.  For a property to be absent you can make it [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and have its property value type be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) (this often allows [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) in there but that's hopefully not an issue).  For a property to be present you should make it (and any parent properties) required.

For your example code that looks like

```
type Parent =
  { nested: { a: string, b?: string }, c?: never } |
  { nested?: { a?: never, b?: string }, c: string }
```

And you can verify that it works as desired:

```
let p: Parent;
p = { nested: { b: "abc" }, c: "def" } // okay
p = { nested: { a: "abc", b: "def" } } // okay
p = { nested: { b: "abc" } } // error
p = { nested: { a: "abc", b: "def" }, c: "ghi" } // error
p = { nested: {}, c: "abc" } // okay
p = { c: "abc" } // okay
```

Note that I didn't reuse your original `Nested` definition.  If you really need to you can use it along with utility types like `Pick`/`Omit` and `Partial`/`Required`:

```
type Parent =
  { nested: Required<Pick<Nested, "a">> & Omit<Nested, "a">, c?: never } |
  { nested?: { a?: never } & Omit<Nested, "a">, c: string }
```

But this only really makes sense if `Nested` has a lot of properties in it, and even then you might want to refactor:

```
interface BaseNested {
  b?: string
  // other props
}
interface NestedWithA extends BaseNested {
  a: string
}
interface NestedWithoutA extends BaseNested {
  a?: never
}
type Parent =
  { nested: NestedWithA, c?: never } |
  { nested?: NestedWithoutA, c: string }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQM6QCbIN4CwAUMsnAPwBcyWUoA5gNzGkBGVNYdITxAvsUFEwATwAOKAApwoEcMgC8LfMhCYc1PGWq0GAGmTsdXBsj4GEHNQDdoZ5AB9lWtVgjYOWitRvQDRzm56MwtjILMhUQlkaVlwSWAEAGsAJQgARwBXYFlsAHkAW2AwAFEwBEVnVXV3ajSsnPcAHgTkpvQ3bAMAIjhugD5+5AAyZELi9pqu5F6BiysIWyh7JxIVVxxPMgWl+1HxsEnOnr7+0MDTASJiUEhYRBQAITgMCA6cfGUA3R5lAHo-sgAPZgAAWdjEUCBYgw-Bu4Gg8CQaCmAHViqCAILICAAD0gIGwGGQz1e73cnzWcDCDDhRFuiIeKM66LBQMyYGxeIJRJJLzeU0ppG81SWdKiUhkck59DgoEqaxcU2o5OwrKx8x8izsfEcVQ27g4qvV7M55x+wSuxAANhAwMgxNRYtLmEQxIp1sqVKxqL1WAhuiFkAhfdgIDBA7qAcCknARMR3QpPZ1NNoZnB-d1-KHw5H7NGgbH426PUqU97fRmA-Yo4DoFCoAnS9Vy15K5nszMwxGgyGZvRQcA89H60DGyWk2WNPhzMH29XazG403J3P05n84DC8vrkQgA)