# How do I get a union of all non-empty subsets of an object type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A type `Subsets<T>` is what I need: it generates a union of all non-empty subsets of type `T` and it differs from the built-in `Partial<T>` in that type `{}` doesn't extend `Subsets<T>`.

For example:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string,
  id: number,
  address: string
}

/** 
 *  Result is expected to be: 
 *  { name: string } | { id: number } | { address: string } 
 *  | { name: string, id: number } | { name: string, address: string } | { id: number, address: string } 
 *  | { name: string, id: number, address: string } 
*/
type Result = Subsets<Person>
```

How to implement `Subset<T>` in TypeScript? Is it feasible to code that in a way like how we solve this kind of problem in algorithm challenges(see this: https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/), by using DFS and backtracking or something else?

Comment: Is this not ["at least one property is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist/49725198#49725198)?

Comment: @kelly That solves my problem. Thanks. I still wonder if there is another way to do that.

Comment: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwBoCj6ATa1AVzIBGCNoSglOneBESJqtBswIBfAgQD0AKg1R22qACVpvADbAo9RFAgAPSAGNgETlGDIoQ6rqLZi5KjTpGJiglKAAfHHNuYn4heBDwyPFJaVkAhWDQr0SfUgo5QOYWKJ5YhASI3L8CjOLkqRkaoIrIrlLBYTEJBrT5ZqzCPUrffPSg4raYjvg67tSm5gSCDTUCUEgDI1NMKABlXgFECGBEAB44JDQAPlV8deh9w+OzgBUrnZ8AbQBpc3QAawgIGQADMoC8ALqUdiRT4AVT+UG+UPBPwhLS+CMYSJRLzRCQAZHsDkcTqcAPJkejAU4vYrfK43fBKT6A4FgyG3AhAA)

Comment: @Filly Thanks a lot! That's the way I'm looking for.

Comment: How does it work?
 First we are creating an object with every like 
 ```types Subsets<T> = { [K in keyof T] : T[K]} ```
 so nothing special is happening here
 The next step is to instantly access all values of the object to recieve an union type of all values
 ```types Subsets<T> = { [K in keyof T]:T[K]}[keyof T] => string | number```
 By creating an inner object we create a union type of every key value pair
 ```types Subsets<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { [U in K]: T[K] } }[keyof T] => { name: string } | { id: number } | { address: string }```

Comment: By omiting every key and in the recursive call we create all subsets of the key value pair

Comment: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&allowUmdGlobalAccess=true&pretty=true&ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwBoCj6ATa1AVzIBGCNvgIBfAgQD0AKhlR28qACUIiXgBtgUeoigQAHpADGwCJyjBkUIdUVFsxclRp1GTKGKgAfHDu7E-ELwnj5+JJyc8GqI1LQMzKH2YY6kFHFuzCz+PEEIob6pzhkJrFARUTEl7gV+XLmCwuWR0YixrqVJhEqFTukd7tn1gY3w2RWt7fE1XgQyUgSgkCpqmtpYAMq8AogQwIgAPHBIaAB8kvhL0Fs7e4cAKqeYUADaANYQIMgAZlD3ALr6AxmVCcPQvVAQABuCEBAH4cF5qI4XgBpHToD5fX4AyjsPwvACqGKgqP+1HuaMBXl6RJJZIpVNCADIoDddvsDgB5Mj0YAHe7ZVGnc74MTvT4-P7-C4EIA)

Comment: I found a bug in my implementation so you should use the link in the previous comment to prevent this bug