# Typescript: type with one requiered property from list of optional

Tags: typescript, type-definition

I have interface with list of optional properties.

```
export interface OptionalIds {
  entityA_Id?: number;
  entityB_Id?: number;
  entityC_Id?: number;
}
```

And I have a requirement that **EXACTLY** one of them **MUST** be defined. Something like that:

```
export interface RequiredBId {
  entityA_Id?: undefined;
  entityB_Id: number;
  entityC_Id?: undefined;
}

export interface RequiredCId {
  entityA_Id?: undefined;
  entityB_Id?: undefined;
  entityC_Id: number;
}

export interface OptionalIds {
  entityA_Id?: number;
  entityB_Id?: number;
  entityC_Id?: number;
}

export type RestrictedOptionalIds = OptionalIds & (RequiredAId | RequiredBId | RequiredCId)
```

**The question is:** Is there other way to achieve described behaviour without weird constructions?

Comment: What do you mean by "without weird constructions"?  There's no built in utility type for this; you can build one but the definition of that is possibly too "weird"?  It looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7y6RW).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Probably you @jcalz are right and it's not clean that exactly I mean by "weird". I achieved the wanted behaviour but with the create a `3 more interfaces` and one more `type` (see `Restricted OptionalIds`). I would like to know is it possibly to implement the same behaviour using build in typescript's utility types, without creation a new types just something like `RequireExactlyOne<OptionalIds>` with the same behaviour as `Restricted OptionalIds`? Because in my particular case `OptionalIds` will contain more than 5 fields.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand if you’re saying that [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7y6RW) is acceptable or not.  If it's not acceptable could you say exactly why?

Comment: @jcalz your approach exacly that I trying to find, how to clean describe the type without creation a lot of interfaces. Could you please add your solution as an answer?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance (currently on mobile)

Comment: What's the difference between that and RequireOnlyOne from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/4529555?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

Thanks to this post for `RequireOnlyOne`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/4529555

```
type RequireOnlyOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>>
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?:
            Required<Pick<T, K>>
            & Partial<Record<Exclude<Keys, K>, undefined>>
    }[Keys]

export interface OptionalIds {
  entityA_Id?: number;
  entityB_Id?: number;
  entityC_Id?: number;
}

const exampleA: RequireOnlyOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityA_Id: 1
}
const exampleB: RequireOnlyOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityB_Id: 1
}

const exampleC: RequireOnlyOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityC_Id: 1
}

// Error
const exampleMultiple: RequireOnlyOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityA_Id: 1,
  entityB_Id: 2,
}

// Error: {} not assignable to RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds, keyof OptionalIds>
const exampleTsError: RequireOnlyOne<OptionalIds> = {

}
```

### Original Answer

Thanks to this post for `RequireAtLeastOne`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198/4529555

```
type RequireAtLeastOne<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> =
    Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> 
    & {
        [K in Keys]-?: Required<Pick<T, K>> & Partial<Pick<T, Exclude<Keys, K>>>
    }[Keys]

export interface OptionalIds {
  entityA_Id?: number;
  entityB_Id?: number;
  entityC_Id?: number;
}

const exampleA: RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityA_Id: 1
}
const exampleB: RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityB_Id: 1
}

const exampleC: RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityC_Id: 1
}

const exampleMultiple: RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds> = {
  entityA_Id: 1,
  entityB_Id: 2
}

// Error: {} not assignable to RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds, keyof OptionalIds>
const exampleTsError: RequireAtLeastOne<OptionalIds> = {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that not exactly I need. The idea was to define type that requires only one  property should be defined and all other cases (no one provided or more than one) will trigger the error.

Comment: Ah ok, so in my answer, you also want TypeScript to error on `const exampleMultiple ...`

Comment: Yes and I achieved the wanted behaviour but with the a weird syntax (see `Restricted OptionalIds`). My question actually could be rephrase: is it possible to simplify `RestrictedOptionalIds` with typescript's utility types as in your answer?

Comment: It's up to you whether you go with your solution or this one: `RequireOnlyOne`
I've updated my answer and referred to the same post by @KPD

Comment: I'm learning TypeScript myself. There is this thing called `Partial`, isn't it the same as this method? Or am I looking at something completely different?

Comment: `Partial` makes all properties optional and none required

Comment: @RobertRendell ah, check. I thought it would be the same, but instead `Partial` will make all of the entries optional.