# VSCode not showing missing props for a React component with complex interface structure on hover

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, react-typescript

I have been searching about this a lot and also gone through many questions but couldn't find the solution. The issue is that I have a React component called Button with a complex prop type like this:

`type ButtonProps = RequireAtLeastOne<BaseButtonProps, "children" | "label" | "icon" | "CustomIcon"> ;`

Where the RequireAtLeastOne is actually explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73935552/8684521
and BaseButtonProps are the following:

```
interface BaseButtonProps
  extends Omit<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, "style"> {
  CustomIcon?: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
  variant?: btnColorVariant;
  label?: string;
  size?: "lg" | "default" | "sm" | "xs";
  icon?:
    | "add"
    | "edit"
    | "delete"
    | "close"
    | "camera"
    | "back"
    | "checkList"
    | "upload"
    | "document"
    | "archive";
  disabled?: boolean;
  loading?: boolean;
  sx?: CSSObject;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  href?: string;
  active?: boolean;
}
```

Now the issue I am facing is that when I try to use the `<Button />` component, it underlines it in red (which it should do) but doesn't provide enough information about the missing required props (which it should also do). For instance, I get the something like the following message on hovering any other component without providing required props:

`Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'CardProps': title, summaryts(2739)`

But for the button component I just see this:

`Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'.ts(2322)`

Even if it should me the list of required and optional props, it would work for me. Pressing `Ctrl + Space`, does help and give me the list, but doesn't help much, it shows a lon list of props and all of them have a `**?**` (are optional - like this: `color?`)

It's very frustrating now, and I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Tried to show a list of required props so that I or any other developer doesn't have to go to the component definition to see the types

Comment: is this material-ui mui?

Comment: just to clarify something. it's working perfectly with you. however, the only problem is that the error message is not descriptive enough, right?

Comment: No, its a custom component and I use `@emotion/styled` for styling the button

Comment: @Normal And yes, you are right, as I am trying to convert it to an npm package, I need to have descriptive interface properties or at-least description error message

Comment: I agree with you that Typescript in itself sucks with that, but TypeScript was designed to lower the developer's productivity in mind, so this was part of the main goals of its existence.

Comment: Can you try the `prettify` helper? https://www.totaltypescript.com/concepts/the-prettify-helper