# How to neatly make one half of a type union required?

Tags: typescript

I've got two subtypes in our application:

```js
export interface QueuedAction extends Action {
  meta: {
    queueName: string;
    overwrite: boolean;
  }
}

export interface BroadcastAction extends Action {
  meta: {
    channelName: string;
  }
}
```

And based on [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist) I union them like so:

```js
export type MetaAction = QueuedAction | BroadcastAction;
```

That's great and all, but I sometimes need to act on a `MetaAction` where one half of the inclusive union is guaranteed.

This has issues:

```js
const wrapBroadcast = (action: AnyAction, channelName = 'DEFAULT_CHANNEL'): MetaAction => ({
  ...action,
  meta: { ...action.meta, channelName },
});

const unwrapBroadcast = (action: MetaAction) => {
  if (!action.meta) return action;

  const { channelName, ...rest } = action.meta; // channelName does not exist on type '{ queueName: string, overwrite?: boolean} | { channelName: string }'
  const unwrappedAction = { ...action, meta: rest };
  return unwrappedAction;
}
```

And if I switch it from `MetaAction` to `BroadcastAction | {BroadcastAction & MetaAction}` (to say, it's always going to have `channelName` but the rest of meta is flexible). I get this error when I go to use it:

> Argument of type 'MetaAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BroadcastAction & MetaAction'

Until I swap the return type of `wrapAction` to match.

Is there a more generic way to declare `BroadcastAction | {BroadcastAction & MetaAction}` given in the future we may end up with more stuff in 'meta' and we'd need this pattern elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make MetaAction generic

Any easy way to make this pattern more generic is to make it ... generic:

```js
export type MetaAction<T extends { meta: any } | {} = {}> = T & (QueuedAction | BroadcastAction);
```

That is, `MetaAction` takes an *option* argument `T`, that must extend anything with `{ meta: any }`, or {}.

And for even more type safety, make your specific MetaActions extend a Base type:

```js
// no meta specified, any action from redux allows for any properties
interface BaseMetaAction extends AnyAction {};

export interface QueuedAction extends BaseMetaAction {
  // as before
}

export interface BroadcastAction extends BaseMetaAction {
  // as before
}

export type MetaAction<T extends BaseMetaAction = AnyAction> = T & (QueuedAction | BroadcastAction);
```

Now you can have MetaAction with or without a required subtype, so long as that subtype extends the BaseMetaAction.

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-aDqGPZwCB8DLMYT4wC+hhrhuSEnCsIhAA) of this setup.

---

Here's how you would and would not use it:

```js
// does work
const myQueuedAction: MetaAction<QueuedAction> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    queueName: 'THE_FOO_QUEUE',
  }
};

const myQueuedSometimesBroadcastAction: MetaAction<QueuedAction> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    queueName: 'THE_FOO_QUEUE',
    channelName: 'THE_FOO_BROADCAST',
  }
};

const myBroadcastSometimesQueuedAction: MetaAction<BroadcastAction> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    queueName: 'THE_FOO_QUEUE',
    channelName: 'THE_FOO_BROADCAST',
  }
};

// does not work
const myQueuedSometimesBroadcastAction: MetaAction<QueuedAction> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    channelName: 'THE_FOO_BROADCAST',
  }
};

const myBroadcastSometimesQueuedAction: MetaAction<BroadcastAction> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    queueName: 'THE_FOO_QUEUE',
  }
};

// constraint not satisfied
type NotASubtype = { meta: {meta: "I'm so meta even this acronym" } }
const myWildMetaAction: MetaAction<NotASubtype> = {
  type: 'foo':
  meta: {
    queueName: 'THE_FOO_QUEUE',
  }
};
```