# Having at least one property of an object be defined in typescript

Tags: typescript

In my program I have this student type, for simplicity I will only keep a few of the original properties

```
export interface Student {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    first_exam_result?: number;
    second_exam_result?: number;
}
```

problem here is that a student may have only attended the first exam or the second exam or both together but there is never a student who doesn't have both. So I changed it to this.

```
export type Student = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
} & ({first_exam_result: number; second_exam_result?: number} | {first_exam_result?: number; second_exam_result: number})
```

This works great when trying to create new variable `const student: Student = {...}` always makes sure one exists.

However the problem comes when trying to use that student variable,

one would assume if `student.first_exam_result === undefined` then `student.second_exam_result` must be a number, however `second_exam_result` is still `number | undefined`, The main problem for me is when I am trying to get the latest exam result I tried using `student.second_exam_result ?? student.first_exam_result` which is still `number | undefined`.

How can I set up the `Student` type in such a way that it behaves as I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript interface require one of two properties to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is limited in its control flow analysis and uses strict checking to ensure type safety.

Examples like `student.second_exam_result ?? student.first_exam_result` will not work.

Something of this sort might work,

```
if (s.second_exam_result) {
  const m = s.second_exam_result; // TypeScript correctly infers this as number
} else {
  const m = s.first_exam_result; // TypeScript still infers this as number | undefined
}
```

But as you see above we have to explicitly check for `s.second_exam_result`. To make the above more effective we will have to use:

```
if (s.second_exam_result) {
  const m = s.second_exam_result; // TypeScript correctly infers this as number
} else if(s.first_exam_result) {
  const m = s.first_exam_result; // TypeScript correctly infers this as number
}
```

But this is too verbose and makes us think if control flow analysis really works as well.
You can read this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48536#issuecomment-1086885375):

> Type narrowing is done only at the level of individual variables, not entire expressions. .... TS has no way to track "at least one of a or b is non-null but I don't know which".

We also have to understand that TS only understands some kinds of [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).