# Ternary spread of optional properties error

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript to make `someFunction` accept `arg1` and either `arg2` or `arg3` you do (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617060/228450):

```
const someFunction = ({
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3,
}: { arg1: number } & (
  | { arg2: number; arg3?: never }
  | { arg3: number; arg2?: never }
)) => {
  
  return "ignore"
};
```

However when I try to use `someFunction` like this:

```
const arg1 = 1
const arg2 = 2
const arg3 = undefined

someFunction({
  arg1,
  ...(arg2 ? {arg2} : {}),
  ...(arg3 ? {arg3} : {})
})
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmAxArmYUCW4YF4YAKAbwCgYYBDAJwHMBGAGguvoCYXLa6BmFgL4AuGCTaMRYNAgBGSGjAEwAZMVYAfUePaTpcmgG5xvAPySkAN3mKNWnr12z5RnuzMwwl6wLIBKXwQAfKKsrDRIUGg0YDAARNh0YCDhsWQCBmRkAPRZHiAw8jTJBDAgANZUAJ5k8MjomDjgpKw8DCLMLRwi7Gm%20mTl5BTRFCoTlVTWIqBhYuGDN3PRtMB2LfN29-bmFxWMVlcRywFRoEEilYAA2B64wAB7F9mznVJeXIADuSAAmfbXTDTmC3Ey1W2m6XGMGwEfTIoEgsFaJQYcPA0G0JR68PRT0IGG%20SAAZthPN8toMdqNSvsyNhCcRXAFyJR-vVZk1mZQQZC1pxWDC0uSkkMRiVxtU6Qz6LwmaxWTNGvNOWswWt%20Py%20j5stthrs8rBxSYAITamDYCBgWBQAAWLw41DA3wxUHkYFoB2AtuAZSyEAADuEqE6becIFRkNQIDAQ9QZCArAU7uG-Zdzh9sDbo7azYSTKbJbdzTACcTSWbEd9vlGY7cAyA-fIoJUAHQ54xmqMlkk-Jjl6iVqNPOsNmhN5umpsNiDAGjYP2wUAIFNUElR9OZ2IAFUqDZgAHJ8UTu989x39ZGIAk3TJU9H8pPznupE4aHvm0R2LwACwAVl8qXlQEOU6RhIWbcCiFuExRFcJQRBIGEwIgp5oJIew4NEAUBTIIA)

Any ideas?

Comment: ① Please post a plaintext [mre]; right now you haven't defined `arg1`, `arg2`, or `arg3` except in your playground link. Could you copy in enough code so nobody needs to leave SO to see your example? ② This has little to do with spread per se... do you expect the type of `(arg2 ? {arg2} :{})` to be `{arg2: number}` instead of `{arg2: number} | {arg2?: undefined}`? If so then I think it's a design limitation as per [ms/TS#33618](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33618). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I have added the missing vars. I assumed, that typescript should understand that the args of someFunction are typed as such that only arg2 or arg3 can be defined, but never both at the same time. Should typescript not understand that?

Comment: You haven't demonstrated "never both at the same time" per se, you've demonstrated specifically "`arg2` is `2` and `arg3` is `undefined`" (the compiler knows that because they're `const`s).  With your example, it's a design limitation as per ms/TS#33618.  Do you want to [edit] to actually demonstrate the "maybe this or maybe that" situation you're describing? It still won't work, but for a different reason (the same as in [ms/#TS52822](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52822), TS isn't a proof solver with counterfactual analysis). Where do you want to go from here?

Comment: Thank you, I am closer to understanding the issue. Even if I do:
`if (arg2 || arg3) {
  someFunction({
    arg1,
    ...(arg2 ? {arg2} : {}),
    ...(arg3 ? {arg3} : {})
  })
}`
I get the error. I guess my question is, if it is even possible to code like this at all in typescript with the given type constraints of someFunction.
In my real world code, arg1, arg2 and arg3 are arguments of another function. Thats why I set arg3 to undefined as it would be with a function argument.

Comment: Re "I guess my question is..." please [edit] to make it explicit inside the post, not just as a comment. And include a [mre] that demonstrates anything you actually care about (e.g., "arguments to another function").  Right now there's not enough information for me to give you anything other than what I've said in previous comments: TypeScript does track multivariable correlations, it can't perform a full counterfactual analysis, as per ms/TS#52822 above.  Maybe with a [mre] I can make another suggestion, but as it's written the answer to the question is still "no, sorry".

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> // error = not okay?!
> // isnt the arg2 and arg2 ternary check/spread the same as the above example with the if?
> // if arg2 is defined it adds the arg2 property. if arg3 is defined, it adds arg3 property.
> // typescript complains with "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)"
> someFunction({
>   arg1,
>   ...(arg2 ? {arg2} : {}),
>   ...(arg3 ? {arg3} : {})
> })
> ```

You're correct that if `arg2` is defined, it's added. You're correct that if `arg3` is defined, it's added. You are *not* correct that this is the same as your previous `if` statements.

> ```
> // no error = okay
> if (arg2) {
>   someFunction({
>     arg1,
>     arg2,
>   })
> }
> ```

This block reads "If `arg2` exists, add `arg2`, omit `arg3`, then call `someFunction()`". This is valid.

The block in question reads "If `arg2` exists, add `arg2`. If `arg3` exists, add that too. Call `someFunction()` whether `arg2` or `arg3` or neither or both were added." This is invalid (exactly one of `arg2` or `arg3` must be added, not neither nor both).

Comment: "The block in question reads "If arg2 exists, add arg2. If arg3 exists, add that too." Thank you, this makes sense. However what I dont get is, that this case should never be possible to occur because the args of someFunction are typed as such that only arg2 or arg3 can be passed, but never both at the same time. Should typescript not understand that?

Comment: @Björn Typescript understands that exactly one of `arg2` or `arg3` must be passed, and will complain if you break this contract (as in this case). For example, if you have `myFunc(arg: string) { ... }` and call `myFunc(62)`, Typescript will complain because it understands that `arg` must be a `string`. It can't stop you from trying to pass a `number`, but it will complain when you do.