# How to handle TypeScript functions with mutually exclusive arguments?

Tags: typescript

I want the `addNumbers` function to always return a number, adding `b` or `c` to `a`. Argument `a` is always required, `b` and `c` are required, but [mutually exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510611/typescript-interface-require-one-of-two-properties-to-exist/60617060#60617060), meaning they are not to be passed at the same time.

I tried:

```
function addNumbers1({
  a,
  b,
  c,
}: { a: number } & (
  | { b: number; c?: never }
  | { c: number; b?: never }
)): 
// here typescript complains "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)"
number {

  if (b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  if (c) {
    return a + c;
  }
}
```

Because of the `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)` error, I tried to check that `a` or `b` are always defined to never allow the case of not having a return type like so:

```
function addNumbers2({
  a,
  b,
  c,
}: { a: number } & (
  | { b: number; c?: never }
  | { c: number; b?: never }
)): number | string {

  // added this line to guard against b or c being undefined.
  if (b === undefined && c === undefined) return "error";

  // at this point b or c should definitely be defined, so one of the following conditions would always return a number.
  // however typescript still complains: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)

  if (b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  if (c) {
    return a + c;
  }
}
```

Now I try something else:

```
function addNumbers3({
  a,
  b,
  c,
}: { a: number } & (
  | { b: number; c?: never }
  | { c: number; b?: never }
)): number | string {

  // make sure again that either b or c is defined
  if (b === undefined && c === undefined) return "error";

  if (b) {
    return a + b;
  } else {
    // but now I get "'c' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048)"
    // how can that be with the check above?
    return a + c;
  }
}
```

What is the best approach to handle this problem? I want to keep the function's arguments as they are.

Edit: The examples would work better if the `number` types were changed to `string` types - there is a separate bug when checking for truthiness of the number 0.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEMBtIgTWByBXAtgIwKYCcDOoBmSAdgMYAuAlgPZF4AW4AbhhFgOaoZFkSgC8oIqkxYIRWKw4ouPNKAAeVUSQh4h6bKAAUc8ONArwPMnRY5w00JUtEqPKJCoB3DLACUAOlA4MLOmTIABxwALhAcMnASAGsqZix8RycPEioUYHBgADYABiyARgB2PJzgACYygA4AFgBWHIAoBpBQAElQJz17eGQNXCsqCEhOgE88LAwyJCwiXnURABo4WAoiNlAAIjQN0CVNkh2yQY3wDY8mwlJKGmXekRx8rQBvBtAIBdfQNA+3kg+AXxCoCeECB800-1AADJtJ8AD7Ar5g4TYADcBgA-GCMPFQP94YiSMi+ui0FjBDiIQ03G4gc0wKYJlYRoEMDgSFgKIEeKkUIFIOBVngNgAxYjkaizAUxPBcFZrUATKYzbyRMgYaTcMQSJXTWZkFksWBUNmCOygVYkSBIWAsADkxFt+FWrjtHi0ZQAzFksm4Ng1waIXp8KPhtGg3MDPm9dSrwKAANRfVGffEhsNaEiRl5vGOTPW8JMkFNvfFplpUaLgEZWUxEJaQSZ4MhYGs4NKTOirNgeXsNS4Sm7gHoo3BlZ6fcA-L7Tv4NQGI8DEkR46Gwt4IkFoZdozHY3H4jeEndYUnkoiU0T4mkn0AIiKchXBt4tYe2iQmCh4SAugagDjgFgEjgGwgq0LIuzKF8GDdqAjoYM6F6wOcbyhuG-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-DiPpVbWXumjGNY69lnOAYeiq7ILBOH1UsGKYMQQGgcQYBiOPGc1xYE+WYAAOoMDwX555gEQQIEgQ0VE-VHKADDiI2tZNx3VAIxqGJAA)

Comment: Why return a string? _Throwing_ in the (theoretically unreachable) neither-defined case would satisfy the compiler: https://tsplay.dev/NroDVm. _Outside_ the function they're mutually exclusive, but _inside_ you basically have `{ a: number; b?: number; c?: number }`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "inside you basically have `{ a: number; b?: number; c?: number }`".
Thats why I tried adding: `if (b === undefined && c === undefined) return "error"`. Should that not tell typescript that `b` and `c` can never be undefined at the same time in the following code? I thought this check is similar to a type guard?

Comment: Isn’t this the same situation as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78037480/2887218) in which I linked you to the relevant GitHub issues saying why TS cannot perform the kind of multi variable analysis you want? I’m still waiting for a reply from you there, by the way.  It’s possible that this version is more amenable to analysis that the one in your other question (TS can do destructured discriminated union analysis) but it’s the same basic situation. What is the difference between this question and the other one?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, you are right. It is essentially the same. I marked it as a duplicate and will follow up in this issue now since I have narrowed in a little better into the issue here. Could you maybe copy your response from the other issue to here?

Comment: The basic issue is the same as in [ms/TS#52822](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52822) and in lots of linked and related issues.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it seems to be the same problem as in ms/TS#52822. But is there anything I can do to make it work without changing the functions signature?

Comment: Do what people are telling you to do and `throw`? This is something like the third round of "this is a TS design limitation" followed by "okay, but can't I do it anyway?". I don't know how else to respond. My only way to proceed here is to write an answer saying it's a limitation and that you have to work around it some way (type assertion, throwing in theoretically unreachable code, etc). If that would be acceptable I'll do it; otherwise I should probably just disengage.  Should I write an answer?

Comment: I would be happy with an answer. Could you explain why throwing would make it work?

Comment: Will do when I get a chance.  [This version](https://tsplay.dev/WookPW) works because the only problem the compiler has is not realizing you can't just fall off the end of the function without returning. By explicitly `throw`ing in that situation you're relieving the compiler of that concern.  Given that the second `if` is apparently unnecessary you could also refactor not to do it, like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WookPW) shows. TS's reachability analysis doesn't always catch all the same things that its control flow analysis does, so sometimes things like this can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) doesn't work by simulating every possible state of the program and making sure the code works for each and every one.  That would be too expensive to be performant. Instead it tends to consider each variable independently, and uses a bunch of heuristics to identify and support common idiomatic JavaScript code.  There are many situations in which TypeScript will fail to notice some invariant, and in these situations you'll need to work around it somehow.

Generally speaking the compiler can't really make many conclusions about *multi-variable* checks, where you need to consider *combinations* of variables to understand what's going on. This is a limitation of TypeScript described at [microsoft/TypeScript#52822](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52822) and other places.

---

In your specific example, though, we can do a bit better. If you are specifically [destructuring a discriminated union type into variables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), the compiler will treat checks of the [discriminant](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) *variable* as narrowing the other variables.  That's what `b` and `c` are in your code, so we should be able to make more headway.

But you still run into a major issue whereby *reachability analysis* that determines whether a function has a `return` statement for every possible control flow path happens before the compiler gets all the information about narrowing.  The canonical GitHub issue for that seems to be [microsoft/TypeScript#21985](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21985). If you have a series of `if`/`else` statements where the last `else` is exhaustive, the compiler won't really consult that before complaining that the function has no return.  The easiest way to fix that is to just eliminate that `else` (since it will always happen if the code gets there):

```
function addNumbers1({ a, b, c }:
  { a: number } & ({ b: number; c?: never } | { c: number; b?: never })
): number {

  if (typeof b === "number") {
    return a + b;
  }

  //if (typeof c === "number") {
  return a + c;
  //}
} // okay
```

---

Or you can use a technique called `assertNever()` which [`throw`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) if you somehow fall off the end of the function. Since that should never happen, you can get the compiler to complain unless the argument to `assertNever()` is considered impossible:

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error("Was not expecting " + x)
}

function addNumbers2({ a, b, c }:
  { a: number } & ({ b: number; c?: never } | { c: number; b?: never })
): number {

  if (typeof b === "number") {
    return a + b;
  }

  if (typeof c == "number") {
    return a + c;
  }

  assertNever(c); // okay
} // okay
```

That works because, after the last block, the compiler realizes `c` cannot be any value. `undefined` was eliminated after the first block, and `number` was eliminated after the second.  When you call `assertNever(c)`, the `c` value [can't exist at all](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  If you failed to eliminate all possibilities (or at least if the compiler couldn't see it), then `assertNever(c)` would throw a compiler error that `c` is not assignable to the `never` type.

And the function is no longer considered non-returning, because `assertNever()` throws unconditionally.  So that's another way to refactor your code slightly to work.  Maybe some future version of TypeScript will remove all need for things like `assertNever()`, but for now that's the closest you can get to having the compiler follow your logic.

---

But again, in general, there will always be cases where you can see that everything is fine but the compiler can't follow the logic because it falls outside of its specific set of analysis tools.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoHIgLYCMCmATgM4CMAFAN4oA0iudEiAvgFwBQii1yriYOAoRaIAZIir0+AvEQDciCAH5p+AG5ERAH26Lpg+fRX91m5gEp25-bOGV2nRDGASoATwAO+OC9yIAvIGIAEQyQsHm3I5chPhQIIRIyIgA1PRyjswOXAD0Oc6unt4uTIH+IWFEEVExcQlJqYoZuTlZzIh5iHAA1shuDqCQsAgoxMREUBimhOQAHqoahNYmizWIUAAWhHAA7iZ7AKKE2zPBAOrIxPxwUIj4s17QMGAA5iGNs5ZZ7INPI2iYAwkABMkmQdAYihYHC4PBsQhE4kkuHhhmUCzMiB01AgqMIClwxjA0xYlmWlTs2ScLnI7i8PnoASCoSB1XsXFq8USKEauGaLCpBVpRQZpXKLNsbOiiFiXIaaQg-O+XEu40Ik2m5Ag5gUnR6fXY7T1vX6QA)